# Can't access object property, even though it shows up in a console log

Tags: javascript, console.log

Below, you can see the output from these two logs. The first clearly shows the full object with the property I'm trying to access, but on the very next line of code, I can't access it with `config.col_id_3` (see the "undefined" in the screenshot?). Can anyone explain this? I can get access to every other property except `field_id_4` as well.

```
console.log(config);
console.log(config.col_id_3);
```

This is what these lines print in Console

[image: Console output]

Comment: can you try `console.log(JSON.stringify(config));` ans share the o/p

Comment: and what about upload_paths? can you get upload_paths in console.log(config.upload_paths);

Comment: also try this, if this works console.log(config['col_id_3']);

Comment: this worked for me. using stringified output as new input for a working object: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))

Comment: Stringifying and then parsing did not solve the issue for me, for some reason. However parsing outright did.

`JSON.parse(obj)`

Comment: I know this is an old post ... `what tool did you use for annotation?` I've been wondering about that for a few months, but none of the tools I've found (Gimp, Nimbus screenshot, MS Paint, IrfanView) for Windows make this ubiquitous white background with drop shadow. Is this a native MAC OS feature?

Comment: For me the problem was that I was executing the javascript that used the object before the javascript that defined the object in the window.

Comment: For some reason all the answers explain how to log the object without the key, not how to access the key

Comment: @EricHepperle-CodeSlayer2010, looks like its Skitch.

Comment: Strange how all of us can be engrossed on __console.log()__ instead of __why data access fails yet the key and data is present__

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(config)).col_id_3` works. but it's ugly... I'm sure there's a reason why it works this way, but I was unable to find one.

Comment: If you find the output of `console.log(yourObject)` is {} with a little blue icon [i], check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546953/cant-access-object-property-even-though-it-shows-up-in-a-console-log/39606500#39606500).

Answer (score 415, accepted):

The output of `console.log(anObject)` is misleading; the state of the object displayed is only resolved when you expand the Object tree displayed in the console, by clicking on `>`. It is **not** the state of the object when you `console.log`'d the object.

Instead, try `console.log(Object.keys(config))`, or even `console.log(JSON.stringify(config))` and you will see the keys, or the state of the object at the time you called `console.log`.

You will (usually) find the keys are being added *after* your `console.log` call.

Comment: Is this behaviour a bug or a feature? If it's a feature, what is the reasoning behind it?

Comment: How does one get around this then? Setting a timeout does NOT seem like a good solution.

Comment: Then how we can access this property, from the object?

Comment: To clarify, is the behaviour of the `>` button different depending on whether an array is being expanded, or an object?

Comment: Doing some testing, it seems that you have come across this issue even with an array, so I would recommend doing JSON.stringify instead.

Comment: This may be caused by setting the property asynchronusly.

Comment: From MDN: "Don't use `console.log(obj)`, use `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)))`. This way you are sure you are seeing the value of `obj` at the moment you log it. Otherwise, many browsers provide a live view that constantly updates as values change. This may not be what you want." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log

Comment: This worked for me @Raffi, thanks! But kind of wtf

Comment: This also helped me debug @Raffi - thx - but the console implementation seems seriously flawed if it's updating objects as values change, how on earth do you debug where/when an object is having a property changed?

Answer (score 108):

I've just had this issue with a document loaded from MongoDB using [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com).

When running `console.log()` on the whole object, all the document fields (as stored in the db) would show up. However some individual property accessors would return `undefined`, when others (including `_id`) worked fine.

Turned out that property accessors only works for those fields specified in my `mongoose.Schema(...)` definition, whereas `console.log()` and `JSON.stringify()` returns all fields stored in the db.

**Solution (if you're using Mongoose)**: make sure all your db fields are defined in `mongoose.Schema(...)`.

Comment: Great explanation of this problem, I figured Mongoose would let me query the json without a schema (in an external script), but would prevent writes. It appears to work because the _id is present, and the console.log says everything else should be accessible, but isn't.  Bizarre.

Comment: Turns out I was seeing this because `JSON.stringify()` (and Node's `console.log()`) change their behaviour if the object given has a `.toJSON()` function. The output you see is what `.toJSON()` returns, and not the original object. Mongoose gives you model objects with a `.toJSON()` that gives the underlying db object. The model object only has accessors for fields you define in the schema, but then all the db fields appear when you log it because you're actually seeing the underlying object returned by `.toJSON()`.

Comment: Why doesn't mongoose allow to read other properties do you have any idea?

Comment: This was helpful for me when uploading a CSV into mongodb and fetching the property. Make sure your names match. Great answer thank you.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was going mad seeing it in the console and not being able to access it. Added the value to my schema and I am good to go. Thanks again!

Comment: In case you'd like to access properties that are not defined in the schema, you can also use the `toObject()` method to convert the returned document to a JavaScript object. See https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toObject

Comment: It is very helpful. I ran into the same problem today while using mongoose+express.

Comment: This is the real answer here

Answer (score 35):

I had the same issue. Solution for me was using the stringified output as input to parsing the JSON. this worked for me. hope its useful to you

```
var x =JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
console.log(x.property_actually_now_defined);
```

Comment: Yes it worked, but why is this required? I already have a JSON, why I need to do this?

Comment: @dilpeshjain I'm not exactly sure, but I would venture that we dont actually have JSON already (perhaps there is a lazy loading type scenario going on,  i am not knowledgeable enough about that at the moment) , but passing whatever we do have into JSON.stringify requires a string to be returned (like the console.log call needs for printing). Because I know I can at least get a string, then I can use that string to create a JSON object for sure right away.

Comment: @jain you need this because javascript is a horrible language

Answer (score 34):

Check if inside the object there's an array of objects. I had a similar issue with a JSON:

```
    "terms": {
        "category": [
            {
                "ID": 4,
                "name": "Cirugia",
                "slug": "cirugia",
                "description": "",
                "taxonomy": "category",
                "parent": null,
                "count": 68,
                "link": "http://distritocuatro.mx/enarm/category/cirugia/"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I tried to access the 'name' key from 'category' and I got the *undefined* error, because I was using:

```
var_name = obj_array.terms.category.name
```

Then I realised it has got square brackets, that means that it has an array of objects inside the category key, because it can have more than one category object. So, in order to get the 'name' key I used this:

```
var_name = obj_array.terms.category[0].name
```

And That does the trick.

Maybe it's too late for this answer, but I hope someone with the same problem will find this as I did before finding the Solution :)

Comment: this is not a solution to the question

Answer (score 34):

The property you're trying to access might not exist yet. Console.log works because it executes after a small delay, but that isn't the case for the rest of your code. Try this:

```
var a = config.col_id_3;    //undefined

setTimeout(function()
{
    var a = config.col_id_3;    //voila!

}, 100);
```

Comment: I used to onload method to get my object values.But still gives me undefined at the first time.. This language makes me dead day by day

Comment: an easy solution would be to implement a watcher promise that checks if the desired property is defined with setTimeout, and resolves + clears the timeout once the property becomes available.

Comment: Wow. In my some 15 years of web programming I had never encountered this and never put thought into how console log works. Your answer helped clear some of that up.

Answer (score 16):

In my case I was passing an object to a promise, within the promise I was adding more key/values to the object and when it was done the promise returned the object.

However, a slight over look on my part, the promise was returning the object before it was fully finished...thus the rest of my code was trying to process the updated object and the data wasn't yet there.  But like above, in the console, I saw the object fully updated but wasn't able to access the keys - they were coming back undefined.  Until I saw this:

```
console.log(obj) ;
console.log(obj.newKey1) ;

// returned in console
> Object { origKey1: "blah", origKey2: "blah blah"} [i]
    origKey1: "blah"
    origKey2: "blah blah"
    newKey1: "this info"
    newKey2: "that info"
    newKey3: " more info"
> *undefined*
```

The [i] is a little icon, when I hovered over it it said `Object value at left was snapshotted when logged, value below was evaluated just now`.  Thats when it occurred to me that my object was being evaluated before the promise had fully updated it.

Answer (score 15):

I just encountered this issue with objects generated by csv-parser from a CSV file that was generated by MS Excel. I was able to access all properties except the first property - but it would show up ok if I wrote the whole object using console.log.

Turned out that the UTF-8 CSV format inserts 3 bytes (ef bb bf) at the start corresponding to an invisible character - which were being included as part of the first property header by csv-parser. Solution was to re-generate the CSV using the non-UTF option and this eliminated the invisible character.

Comment: You are a hero! Thanks for posting this. I was pulling my hair out.

Comment: Thanks again for posting this! Saved my night!

Comment: Awesome find. Thanks!

Comment: i was seeing this exact same issue. i solved it by using data[Object.keys(data)[0]] to get the first value rather than changing the csv

Comment: Wow, indeed it does! Thank you for figuring this out. I knew there had to be some weird characters in there for JS to be quoting my key in the log output, but this solved it. Well done.

Comment: Looks like the `csv-parse` library has an option to strip these: https://csv.js.org/parse/options/bom/#option-code-classlanguage-textbomcode

Answer (score 14):

My data was just json data string . (This variable was stored as json string in the session).

```
console.log(json_string_object)
```

-> returns just the representation of this string and there is no way to make difference whether is string or object.

So to make it work I just needed to convert it back to real object:

```
object = JSON.parse(json_string_object);
```

Comment: This was the only answer that worked for me and is also mentioned in the comments of the original question, this should be higher.

Comment: This was my situation as well. It was super confusing, until I logged the `typeof(variable_name)`.

Answer (score 13):

I struggled with this issue today, and thought I'll leave a reply with my solution.

I was fetching a data object via ajax, something like this:
`{"constants": {"value1":"x","value2":"y"},"i18n" {"data1":"x", "data2":"y"}}`

Let's say this object is in a variable called data. Whenever I referenced `data.i18n` I got `undefined`.

1. `console.log(data)` showed the object as expected
2. `console.log(Object.keys(data))` said `["constants","i18n"]` as expected
3. Renaming *i18n* to *inter* didn't change anything
4. I even tried to switch the data to make "i18n" the first object
5. Moved code around to make absolutely sure the object was completely set and  there was no problem with the ajax promise.

Nothing helped... Then on the server side I wrote the data to the php log, and it revealed this:

`{"constants": {"value1":"x","value2":"y"},"\u045618n" {"data1":"x", "data2":"y"}}`

The "i" in the index key was actually a u0456 (cyrillic i). This was not visible in my php editor or the browser console log. Only the php log revealed this... That was a tricky one...

Comment: This was also my issue; had a Cyrillic 'c' character instead in some of the instances. I found it by searching my file for the string I expected; the suspicious one was not selected, so that told me there was a wrong character that was invisible to the eye.

Comment: This answer actually helped me find my solution. My issue was I had misspelled my variable name. I did "udpate" instead of "update" lol

Answer (score 12):

In 2018 Mozilla warns us in the [Mozilla Docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log#Logging_objects)!

I quote ***"Logging Objects"***:

> **Don't use `console.log(obj);`,**
>   use `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)));`.
>
> This way you are sure you are seeing the value of obj at the moment
>   you log it.

Answer (score 9):

For me it turned out to be a Mongoose-related problem.

I was looping over objects that I got from a Mongo query. I just had to remove:

```js
items = await Model.find()
```

And replace it by:

```js
items = await Model.find().lean()
```

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to `.lean()`. I did not know it existed and after researching it on Monggose's website, I'm glad I found it. Thanks for the great nugget.

Comment: nice answer, good knowledge

Answer (score 9):

If this is an issue occurring when working with **Mongoose**, the following may happen:

```
console.log(object)
```

returns everything, including the desired key.

```
console.log(object.key)
```

returns undefined.

If that is happening, it means that the key is missing from the Mongoose Schema. Adding it in will resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been beating my head against a wall.

Answer (score 4):

This might help somebody as I had a similar issue in which the JSON.parse() was returning an object that I could print on the console.log() but I couldn't acccess the specific fields and none of the above solution worked for me. Like using the combination of JSON.parse() with JSON.stringify().

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(responseText))

// where responseText is a JSON String returned by the server.

console.log(jsonObj) ///Was printing the object correctly
console.log(jsonObj.Body) /// Was printing Undefined
```

I ended up solving the problem by using a different parser provided by ExtJs Ext.decode();

```
var jsonObj = Ext.decode(responseText)
console.log(jsonObj.Body) //Worked...
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and no solution above worked for me and it sort of felt like guess work thereafter. However, wrapping my code which creates the object in a `setTimeout` function did the trick for me.

```
setTimeout(function() {
   var myObj = xyz; //some code for creation of complex object like above
   console.log(myObj); // this works
   console.log(myObj.propertyName); // this works too
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I've just had the same issue with a document loaded from MongoDB using Mongoose.

Turned out that i'm using the property `find()` to return just one object, so i changed  `find()` to `findOne()` and everything worked for me.

Solution (if you're using Mongoose): Make sure to return one object only, so you can parse its `object.id` or it will be treated as an array so you need to acces it like that `object[0].id`.

Comment: This helped me some by helping me clean up my code. I have a function doing the Mongoose query (with `.findOne()` now, thanks to you) and it returns an Object I can access in dot notation inside the function. I call that Mongoose function further down in code by `const test = await mongoFunction(query)` and, unfortunately, my problem is the returned `test` is an array with the Object inside of it `[ {object} ]` that I cannot access in dot notation. It is driving me nuts!

Comment: This was my solution! Now *console.log()* works normal! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

if you're using `TYPESCRIPT` and/or `ANGULAR`, it could be this!

`.then((res: any) => res.json())`

setting the response type to **any** fixed this issue for me, I couldn't access properties on the response until i set **res: any**

see this question [Property '_body' does not exist on type 'Response'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574305/property-body-does-not-exist-on-type-response)

Answer (score 2):

In My case, it just happens to be that even though i receive the data in the format of a model like  `myMethod(data:MyModelClass)`  object till the received object was of type string.
Which is y in console.log(data) i get the content.
Solution is just to parse the JSON(in my case)

```
const model:MyMOdelClass=JSON.parse(data);
```

Thought may be usefull.

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar issue, hope the following solution helps someone.
You can use **`setTimeout`** function as some guys here suggesting, but you never know how exactly long does your browser need to get your object defined.

Out of that I'd suggest using **`setInterval`** function instead. It will wait until your object `config.col_id_3` gets defined and then fire your next code part that requires your specific object properties.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){

    var fileInterval = setInterval(function() {
        if (typeof config.col_id_3 !== 'undefined') {

            // do your stuff here

            clearInterval(fileInterval); // clear interval
        }
    }, 100); // check every 100ms

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue or maybe just related.

For my case I was accessing properties of an object but one was undefined. I found the problem was a white-space in the server side code while creating the key,val of the object.

My approach was as follows...

[image: creating my object... notice the white-space in "word"]

[image: response I get from my REST API]

[image: javascript code to log the values]

[image: log results from console]

After removing the white-space from the server-side code creating the object, I could now access the property as below...

[image: result after removing whitespace]

This might not be the issue with the case of the subject question but was for my case and may be so for some one else. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this issue as well, and long story short my API was returning a string type and not JSON.   So it looked exactly the same when you printed it to the log however whenever I tried to access the properties it gave me an undefined error.

API Code:

```
     var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StatusResult>(string Of object);
     return Json(response);
```

previously I was just returning:

```
return Json(string Of object);
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing check the type like below:

```
console.log(typeof config);
```

If the command above prints object then it is very easy you just use the bracket notation. Bracket notation can be quite useful if you want to search for a property’s values dynamically.

Execute the command below:

```
console.log(config[col_id_3]);
```

If it a string you need to parse in object first. To do that you need to execute the command below:

```
var object = JSON.parse(config);
```

And after that use bracket notation to access the property like below:

```
console.log(object[col_id_3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue like this, and found the solution was to do with Underscore.js. My initial logging made no sense:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));

> {
>   "code": "foo"
> }

console.log(obj.code);

> undefined
```

I found the solution by also looking at the keys of the object:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.keys(obj)));

> ["_wrapped","_chain"]
```

This lead me to realise that `obj` was actually an Underscore.js wrapper around an object, and the initial debugging was lying to me.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem (when developing for SugarCRM), where I start with:

```
var leadBean = app.data.createBean('Leads', {id: this.model.attributes.parent_id});

// This should load object with attributes 
leadBean.fetch();

// Here were my attributes filled in with proper values including name
console.log(leadBean);

// Printed "undefined"
console.log(leadBean.attributes.name);
```

Problem was in `fetch()`, its async call so I had to rewrite my code into:

```
var leadBean = app.data.createBean('Leads', {id: this.model.attributes.parent_id});

// This should load object with attributes 
leadBean.fetch({
    success: function (lead) {
        // Printed my value correctly
        console.log(lead.attributes.name);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this is helpful for someone, I had a similar problem, and it's because someone created an override for .toJSON in the object I was working with.  So the object was something like:

```
{
  foo: {
         bar: "Hello"
         baz: "World"
       }
}
```

But .toJSON() was:

```
toJSON() {
  return this.foo
}
```

So when I called JSON.stringify(myObject) it returned "{"bar": "Hello", "baz": "World"}".  However, Object.keys(myObject) revealed the "foo".

Comment: `toJson()` this is the point that nobody has mentioned here. I don't know why this answer was downvoted since this is a way to create an object that has a different value from it's json or console representation. I didn't know it existed until I uncovered it in a different answer, and I think this answer should be upvoted since it is a point to consider with these types of issues.

Comment: Considering the number of answers that have exactly 0 points, I think someone just went through downvoting everything.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem today. In my case the keys were nested, i.e key1.key2.
I split the keys using split() and then used the square bracket notation, which did work for me.

```
var data = {
    key1: {
          key2: "some value"
       }
}
```

I split the keys and used it like this, data[key1][key2] which did the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today. Problem was caused by uglify-js. After I executed same non-uglified code problem was solved. Removing of

```
--mangle-props
```

from uglify-js was enough to have working uglified code.

Perhaps, the best practice is to use some prefix for properties that has to be mangled with regex rule for uglify-js.

Here is the source:

```
var data = JSON.parse( content);
...
this.pageIndex = parseInt(data.index);
this.pageTotal = parseInt(data.total);
this.pageLimit = parseInt(data.limit);
```

and here is how it was uglified:

```
var n = JSON.parse( t);
...
this._ = parseInt(n.index), this.g = parseInt(n.total), this.D = parseInt(n.C)
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the JSON stringify/parse worked for me.

```
formValues.myKey:               undefined
formValues.myKey with timeout:  content
```

I wanted the value of `formValues.myKey` and what did the trick was a setTimeout 0 like in the example below. Hope it helps.

```
console.log('formValues.myKey: ',formValues.myKey);
setTimeout( () => { 
  console.log('formValues.myKey with timeout: ', formValues.myKey);
}, 0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue today in React. Eventually realised that the problem was being caused by the state not being set yet. I was calling `user.user.name` and although it was showing up in the console, I couldn't seem to access it in my component till I included a check to check if `user.user` was set and then calling `user.user.name`.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you had applied any filters in the console. It happens to me in chrome console.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this frustrating problem, I tried the `setTimeout()` and the `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` solutions even if I knew it wouldn't work as I think they're mostly JSON or Promise related problems, sure enough it didn't work. In my case though, I didn't notice immediately that it was a silly mistake. I was actually accessing a property name with a different casing. It's something like this:

```js
const wrongPropName = "SomeProperty"; // upper case "S"
const correctPropName = "someProperty"; // lower case "s"
const object = { someProperty: "hello world!" };

console.log('Accessing "SomeProperty":', object[wrongPropName]);
console.log('Accessing "someProperty":', object[correctPropName])
```

It took me a while to notice as the property names in my case can have either all lower case or some having mixed case. It turned out that a function in my web application has something that makes a mess of my property names (it has a `.toLowerCase()` next to the generated key names ).

So, lesson learned, check property name casing more properly.

Answer (score 0):

I was not getting the MongoDB error message in the thrown error in my NodeJS API response, so I did the following

```
// It was not working
console.log(error.message) // prints the error
let response = error;
// message property was not available in the response.
/* 
{
  "status": "error",
  "error": {
    "driver": true,
    "name": "MongoError",
    "index": 0,
    "code": 11000,
    "keyPattern": {
      "event_name": 1
    },
    "keyValue": {
      "event_name": "followup"
    }
  }
}
*/
```

```
// so I did this
let message = error.message;
let response = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(error));
response.message = message;
// message property is now available in the response.
/* 
{
  "status": "error",
  "error": {
    "driver": true,
    "name": "MongoError",
    "index": 0,
    "code": 11000,
    "keyPattern": {
      "event_name": 1
    },
    "keyValue": {
      "event_name": "followup"
    },
    "message": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: mycollections.notificationevents index: event_name_1 dup key: { event_name: \"followup\" }"
  }
}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

In the context of this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52994419

The solution to re-generate the files may not always be feasible. To strip out the "non-space" characters before the string. So, if you can `trim` the field names, that would clean up things.

Something like this:

```
const records = parse(csvData, {
      columns: (colNameArray) => {
        return colNameArray.map((value, index) => {          
          return index === 0 ? value.trim() : value;
        });
      },
      onRecord: mapper.mapRow
    });
```

If you don't care about the performance on this one, can skip the `index` check too.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried plenty of answers on this question
finally found what has happen.

Although object is print on `console.log(foo)` **get** and **set** methods generated only when using `new Foo()`
you have to initialize instance with plane js object

please have a look : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41153231/5954248

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me (using Vue JS):

```
const auth = undefined;

console.log(auth); // undefined

// ✅ No error
console.log(auth?.user?.name); // undefined
```

Answer (score -1):

Well I passed by a situation that really scared me about new loops and thanked the old school I am.

The **forEach loop** and also **for( a in obj ) loop** BOTH produces FALSE INFORMATION and bugs, depending on the type of object and its properties!!

The old and good

```
for(var i=0, max=arr.length; i<max; i++)
{ //Properties available correctly!

   arr[i].property        //both work inside old school loop!
   arr[i][property]  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem.

From the server, I was returning data in json_encode.
Like this

```
 echo json_encode($res);
```

After I returned a simple PHP array without json_encode, it solved the problem.

```
return $res;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).