# JSON to TypeScript class instance?

Tags: json, typescript, deserialization

I've done quite some research, but I'm not totally satisfied with what I found. Just to be sure here's my question:
What is actually the most robust and elegant automated solution for deserializing JSON to TypeScript runtime class instances?

Say I got this class:

```
class Foo {
  name: string;
  GetName(): string { return this.name };
}
```

And say I got this JSON string for deserialization:

```
{"name": "John Doe"}
```

What's the best and most maintainable solution for getting an instance of a Foo class with the name set to "John Doe" and the method GetName() to work? I'm asking very specifically because I know it's easy to deserialize to a pure data-object. I'm wondering if it's possible to get a class instance with working methods, without having to do any manual parsing or any manual data copying. If a fully automated solution isn't possible, what's the next best solution?

Comment: Since the `name` field is public, what´s the `GetName` method for?

Comment: I guess you can consider it a doctored example ;)
The point was to get an answer that yields a true instance of class that includes all methods as well, not just a deserialized class instance that contains only the data, and doesn't allow to invoke the declared methods.

Answer (score 97):

This question is quite broad, so I'm going to give a couple of solutions.

### Solution 1: Helper Method

Here's an example of using a Helper Method that you could change to fit your needs:

```
class SerializationHelper {
    static toInstance<T>(obj: T, json: string) : T {
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(json);

        if (typeof obj["fromJSON"] === "function") {
            obj["fromJSON"](jsonObj);
        }
        else {
            for (var propName in jsonObj) {
                obj[propName] = jsonObj[propName]
            }
        }

        return obj;
    }
}
```

Then using it:

```
var json = '{"name": "John Doe"}',
    foo = SerializationHelper.toInstance(new Foo(), json);

foo.GetName() === "John Doe";
```

**Advanced Deserialization**

This could also allow for some custom deserialization by adding your own `fromJSON` method to the class (this works well with how `JSON.stringify` already uses the `toJSON` method, as will be shown):

```
interface IFooSerialized {
    nameSomethingElse: string;
}

class Foo {
  name: string;
  GetName(): string { return this.name }

  toJSON(): IFooSerialized {
      return {
          nameSomethingElse: this.name
      };
  }

  fromJSON(obj: IFooSerialized) {
        this.name = obj.nameSomethingElse;
  }
}
```

Then using it:

```
var foo1 = new Foo();
foo1.name = "John Doe";

var json = JSON.stringify(foo1);

json === '{"nameSomethingElse":"John Doe"}';

var foo2 = SerializationHelper.toInstance(new Foo(), json);

foo2.GetName() === "John Doe";
```

### Solution 2: Base Class

Another way you could do this is by creating your own base class:

```
class Serializable {
    fillFromJSON(json: string) {
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(json);
        for (var propName in jsonObj) {
            this[propName] = jsonObj[propName]
        }
    }
}

class Foo extends Serializable {
    name: string;
    GetName(): string { return this.name }
}
```

Then using it:

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.fillFromJSON(json);
```

There's too many different ways to implement a custom deserialization using a base class so I'll leave that up to how you want it.

Comment: Thank you. Both of these solutions seem a lot better than all the ones I've found before. Gonna give them a try a little later.

Comment: @Klaus an issue with this is if you have nested objects. For example, if `Foo` had a property that was of type `Bar`. That problem is a bit more complex...

Comment: Damn. Nested objects was actually another issue I was about to ask at a later point. I feel like I don't know enough about TypeScript yet to be able to properly ask that follow up question.
I wouldn't mind if you'd post a few key-words though that would allow me to look for solutions for the nested problem on my own though. Again, thanks already for your in depth answer above.

Comment: To support nesting, could it be as simple as making the `fillFromJson` method recursive? I.e., your null check could determine whether the current `json` argument is an Object - if so, the recursion continues: `this[propName] = typeof jsonObj[propName] == 'object' ? fillFromJson(jsonObj[propName]) : jsonObj[propName]`. Have you tried this? I can try and see how it goes, I'm just wondering if you knew of any gotchas that could save me time. Thanks!

Comment: @DannyBullis I am wanting to come back and look at this problem in order to develop a better solution. Sometime in the future though. Until then, here's another way that does it with [recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32169241/188246). Basically, you'll need to know the type of the properties too.

Comment: @DavidSherret thanks for the quick reply - yeah, I just looked at that post - that's how I ended up here :]. I had a question about that one too, I will post it there. Thanks again

Answer (score 62):

You can now use `Object.assign(target, ...sources)`. Following your example, you could use it like this:

```
class Foo {
  name: string;
  getName(): string { return this.name };
}

let fooJson: string = '{"name": "John Doe"}';
let foo: Foo = Object.assign(new Foo(), JSON.parse(fooJson));

console.log(foo.getName()); //returns John Doe
```

`Object.assign` is part of [ECMAScript 2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.assign) and is currently available in most modern browsers.

Comment: In case the default constructor is missing on `Foo`, the target instance can be created through `Object.create(Foo.prototype)`, bypassing the constructor altogether.

Comment: Does not work for nested objects

Comment: @jzqa Can you give an example where it fails? I see its copying fine.

Comment: Nested objects won't be mapped to their strong types when using normal `JSON` parsing. I suggest using a package like [class-transformer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-transformer) to properly map the objects and their types for any nested object. Their documentation is relatively easy to understand and get going as well

Answer (score 19):

> What is actually the most robust and elegant automated solution for deserializing JSON to TypeScript runtime class instances?

Using [property decorators](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Decorators.md#property-decorators) with [ReflectDecorators](https://github.com/rbuckton/ReflectDecorators) to record runtime-accessible type information that can be used during a deserialization process provides a *surprisingly* clean and widely adaptable approach, that also fits into existing code beautifully. It is also fully automatable, and works for nested objects as well.

An implementation of this idea is [TypedJSON](https://github.com/JohnWhiteTB/TypedJSON), which I created precisely for this task:

```
@JsonObject
class Foo {
    @JsonMember
    name: string;

    getName(): string { return this.name };
}
```

```auto
var foo = TypedJSON.parse('{"name": "John Doe"}', Foo);

foo instanceof Foo; // true
foo.getName(); // "John Doe"
```

Comment: If you want more people to use your library, I would recommend publishing on npm and fixing those typings.... with a package.json pointing to your index.d.ts file

Comment: Does this library work with React?

Comment: @Keselme Yes, I myself use it in various projects where the view layer is implemented using React.

Comment: @JohnWeisz, I have a problem using it with React, I get an error that says `could not resolve detected property constructor at runtime.` I actually opened an issue could you take a look at it? https://github.com/JohnWeisz/TypedJSON/issues/130

Answer (score 4):

Why could you not just do something like this?

```
class Foo {
  constructor(myObj){
     Object.assign(this, myObj);
  }
  get name() { return this._name; }
  set name(v) { this._name = v; }
}

let foo = new Foo({ name: "bat" });
foo.toJSON() //=> your json ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work with nested objects.

Answer (score -2):

The best solution I found when dealing with Typescript classes and json objects: add a constructor in your Typescript class that takes the json data as parameter. In that constructor you extend your json object with jQuery, like this: $.extend( this, jsonData). $.extend allows keeping the javascript prototypes while adding the json object's properties.

```
export class Foo
{
    Name: string;
    getName(): string { return this.Name };

    constructor( jsonFoo: any )
    {
        $.extend( this, jsonFoo);
    }
}
```

In your ajax callback, translate your jsons in a your typescript object like this:

```
onNewFoo( jsonFoos : any[] )
{
  let receviedFoos = $.map( jsonFoos, (json) => { return new Foo( json ); } );

  // then call a method:
  let firstFooName = receviedFoos[0].GetName();
}
```

If you don't add the constructor, juste call in your ajax callback:

```
let newFoo = new Foo();
$.extend( newFoo, jsonData);
let name = newFoo.GetName()
```

...but the constructor will be useful if you want to convert the children json object too. See my detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875636/how-do-i-cast-a-json-object-to-a-typescript-class/41046474#41046474).