# why does defining type of function parameters not perform conversion

Tags: typescript, angular

I am looking for a little clarity.  I have a typescript (I'm using 1.7) function that is tied to the change event of a select option / drop down in the html:

```
    toggleWorker(stsID: number): void {
    // get status object by selected staus ID
    let cStatus: Status = this.stsList.filter((s: Status) => s.StatusID === stsID)[0];
    // if status requires a worker to be assigned then toggle requireWorker
    if (cStatus.RequireWorker) {
        this.requireWorker = true;
    } else if (!cStatus.RequireWorker) {
        this.requireWorker = false;
    }
}
```

here is the HTML declaration:

```
   <div class="large-3 columns">
       <label >Trade Status
           <select id="StatusID" 
               [(ngModel)]="currentTrade.StatusID"
               [ngFormControl]="shiftForm.controls['StatusID']"
               (change)="toggleWorker($event.target.value)" >
               <option *ngFor="#sts of stsList" value="{{sts.StatusID}}"
                  >{{sts.Title}}</option>
           </select>
       </label> 
   </div>
```

here is the class of the status object so you can see that the StatusID is a type number:

```
export class Status {

StatusID: number;
PortalID: number;
Title: string;
Code: string;
RequireWorker: boolean;

constructor(obj?: any) {
    this.StatusID = obj && obj.StatusID || 0;
    this.PortalID = obj && obj.PortalID || 0; 
    this.Title = obj && obj.Title || null;
    this.Code = obj && obj.Code || null;
    this.RequireWorker = obj && obj.RequireWorker || false;
}
```

}

I have a [sample fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/krisis/h8dk17ce/) where this works perfectly.

But when I tried to use this in my angular2 app it did not work unless i explicitly converted the type of the function parameter.  See the following change:

```
let cStatus: Status = this.stsList.filter((s: Status) => s.StatusID === Number(stsID))[0];
```

Notice the addition of **Number(stsID)**

**QUESTION:**
Can someone help me understand what is going on here.  Is the type declaration of the function parameter only for internal typechecking, I assumed it would perform a conversion to that type.

I hope that makes sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you assumed types are only for static type checking. There is no conversion going on. You need to convert explicitly.

There is also [type casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32167593/how-to-do-runtime-type-casting-in-typescript) where you express that type checking can assume that a value is of a certain type but that also doesn't convert a value if it actually is not of that type.

Comment: thanks, so what is best practice for type conversions in this situation?  Do you try to convert function parameters as the first step in the function for all parameters?

Comment: I guess I would create a custom ControlValueAccessor like shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31879497/angular2-radio-button-binding or a getter/setter that does the conversion.