# Whats the easiest way to create a TypeScript object with JSON as input?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

In Angular2 (TypeScript) I have a class with the following constructor:

```
 export class DataModel {
    constructor(public date_of_visit: string,
                public gender: boolean,
                public year_of_birth: number,
                public height: number,
                public weight: number){}
 }
```

I have the following JSON object:

```
json = {"date_of_visit": "23/09/2016", "gender": 1, "year_of_birth": 1975, "height":185, "weight": 85}
```

**Question:** Whats the easiest way to create a DataModel instance with the JSON data as input? Something like `new DataModel(**json)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON to TypeScript class instance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29758765/json-to-typescript-class-instance)

Answer (score 1):

For compile time casting, this will do:

```
let dataModel = {"date_of_visit": "23/09/2016", "gender": 1, "year_of_birth": 1975, "height":185, "weight": 85} as DataModel;
```

Comment: FYI, this is a type-_assertion_, which is a compile-time construct, and not a type-_cast_, which would be a runtime-time construct. This effectively means that the object created from parsing the JSON will be an `Object` instance at runtime, and not a `DataModel` instance. This is fine as long as you don't use `instanceof`, or define methods, getters, setters, or anything that is not inherently present in the parsed JSON itself.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that @JohnWhite. 
I think the answer Im looking for is type-cast, because I need to call methods of DataModel. Can you show an example of this?

Comment: I think I found the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32167593/how-to-do-runtime-type-casting-in-typescript

Comment: IMO, this is a complete unknown in TypeScript for now. There is no standardized methodology for doing an actual type-cast, which can be credited to the relatively young age of TypeScript, and that one of its goals is minimizing any runtime overhead. However, there's an experimental project I started working on, [TypedJSON](https://github.com/JohnWhiteTB/TypedJSON), which does exactly what you are looking for: creating a user-defined class instance from JSON. It has its limitations, but it is solid for general use, and its syntax is extremely lightweight. I can post an answer with it.

Comment: I'll take a look at your project, thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Casting should get you through:

```
let model: DataModel = {"date_of_visit": "23/09/2016", "gender": 1, "year_of_birth": 1975, "height":185, "weight": 85} as DataModel;
```

Comment: It is worth noting that the preferred way of doing a type-_assertion_ is `obj as Type`.