# Assign ajax result to interface inclusive methods

Tags: casting, typescript

I'm quite new to Typescript and have a bit of a problem to get my code working. I have the following interface/class structure

```
interface IInterface {
  id : number;
  method() : string;
}

class IClass implements IInterface {
  id : number;
  method() : string { return "foo";}
}
```

Now I want to get some data from a webservice via the following call

```
$.get("/some/url", (data : Array<IInterface>) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        console.log(data[i].id);
        console.log(data[i].method());
    }
});
```

While this compiles perfectly fine in typescript and also all properties are set perfectly fine, I get a runtime TypeError `data[i].method is not a function`

So now my question: How can I cast/assign (?) this correctly, so that the methods are also available in the resulting JavaScript?

**UPDATE** As requested: a dump of the data I get from the webservice.

```
data = [{id : 1}, {id : 2}, ...]
```

Of course, this is a simplified example, the real classes/interfaces have some more properties (they all are assigned correctly), but also only one method (so far, when I get it working, some more will follow).

Comment: you are missing a bracket: `console.log(data[i].method());`

Comment: @FlorianTopf Sorry for the typo. The parenthesis is contained in the original code (without it, it would not compile). I updated my question.

Comment: can you dump the whole `data[i]` object?

Comment: I'm not sure, what you mean by dump. The data[i] i receive from the webservice are basically just a plain object with a bunch of properties. Please see my update

Comment: ok, then you need to map over the results and create new classes:

`data.map((d) => return new IClass(d.id)).` something like that. But you need to introduce a constructor in `IClass`

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that.

Comment: @FlorianTopf that looks like the right answer, please consider making an answer out of it. :)

Comment: @toskv glad to hear. Will do in a minute. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is what you receive are objects which are complying to the interface, but they don't have a `method` property inside.

What you need to do in order to get this working is, you need to create new objects from type `IClass` in the reponse handler which extend the objects inside `data`:

```
$.get("/some/url", (data: Array<IInterface>) => {
    return data.map((d) => return new IClass(d.id));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem of converting JSON objects into instances of the classes. There are some proposals discussed here: [JSON to TypeScript class instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29758765/json-to-typescript-class-instance)

Below is the solution I came up to do such deserialization:

```
export class Helper
{
    public static DESCRIPTOR_SIGN = '$';

    private static m_entityModules = [];

    private static ReviveDateTime(key: any, value: any): any 
    {
        if (typeof value === 'string')
        {
            let a = /\/Date\((\d*)\)\//.exec(value);
            if (a)
            {
                return new Date(+a[1]);
            }
        }

        return value;
    }

    private static RessurectValue(json: any, environments: any[]): any
    {
        if(json == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else if(Helper.IsString(json))
        {
            return json;
        }
        else if(json instanceof Date)
        {
            return json;
        }
        else if(typeof json === 'object') 
        {
            return Helper.RessurectInternal(json, environments);
        } 
        else 
        {
            return json;
        }
    }

    private static RessurectInternal(json: any, environments: any[]): any 
    {
        var instance;

        if(!json[Helper.DESCRIPTOR_SIGN])
        {
            instance = {};
        }
        else
        {
            instance = Helper.CreateObject(json[Helper.DESCRIPTOR_SIGN]);

            if(Helper.IsUndefined(instance))
            {
                throw new Error('Unknown type to deserialize:' + json[Helper.DESCRIPTOR_SIGN]);
            }              
        }

        for(var prop in json) 
        {
            if(!json.hasOwnProperty(prop) || prop === Helper.DESCRIPTOR_SIGN) 
            {
                continue;
            }

            let val = json[prop];
            instance[prop] = Helper.Ressurect(val, environments);
        }

        return instance;
    }

    private static CreateObject(className: string, environments?: any[]): any
    {
        let instance: any;
        for(let e of environments)
        {
            var construct = e[className];

            if(!Helper.IsUndefined(construct))
            {
                instance = new construct(); 
                break;
            }
        }

        return instance;
    }

    private static IsNumber(val: any): boolean
    {
        return typeof val == 'number' || val instanceof Number;
    }

    private static IsUndefined(val: any): boolean
    {
        return typeof(val) === 'undefined';
    }

    private static IsString(val: any): boolean
    {
        return typeof val == 'string' || val instanceof String;
    }

    /**
     * Deserialize json object object into TypeScript one.
     * @param json json object that must have its class name in '$' field
     * @param environments list of modules containing all types that can be encountered during deserialization
     * @return deserialized typescript object of specified type  
     */
    public static Ressurect(val: any, environments: any[]): any 
    {
        if(val instanceof Array)
        {
            if(val.length == 0)
            {
                return val;
            }
            else 
            {
                let firstElement = val[0];
                if(typeof firstElement !== 'object')
                {
                    return val;
                }
                else
                {
                    let arr = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) 
                    {
                        var element = val[i];
                        arr.push(Helper.RessurectValue(element, environments));
                    }

                    return arr;
                }   
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Helper.RessurectValue(val, environments);
        }
    }
}
```

Some notes for the above. It works based on the assumption that:

1. There is a parameterless constructor in every type that can be deserialized.
2. Every JSON object contain field '$' with its class name inside.

Sample of usage. Lets suppose yu have defined all your serializable classes in one external mode called 'Types'. Then to deserialize JSON object you write:

```
import * as types from './Types'

//Some code to get jsonObj that has jsonObj.$ set to "RealObject" - a type from "Types" module

let realObj = <types.RealObject>Helper.Resurrect(jsonObj, [types]);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice answer, but at the current time I prefer something simpler. Thanks anyway.