# Cast JSON object to TypeScript class instance

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have a class which have a method:

```
 export class ItemType {
        id1: string;
        description: string;

        treeItemTypeDescription(): string {
            return this.id1 +  this.description;
        }
 }
```

I get the data of this class form web service and want to call this method:

```
itemTypeResource.parents(this.originalPosition).then((parents: app.domain.ItemType[]) => {
      console.log(typeof(parents[0]));
      console.log(parents[0].treeItemTypeDescription());
});
```

But get the error:

```
TypeError: parents[0].treeItemTypeDescription is not a function
```

I think the reason of error the JS-object is not linked with TS-object. But I don't know how to fix it.

**Update:**

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(parents[0]));

gives only fields, but not methods:

```
 ["autoincrementedId", "description", "entityType", "excelId", "excelParentId", "id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5", "parentAutoId"]
```

**Update2:**

If I create the object by myself all works fine:

```
  var s = new app.domain.ItemType();
  s.id1 = "1";
  s.description = "some";
  console.log(s.treeItemTypeDescription());
```

Comment: `treeItemTypeDescription` vs `treeItemDescription` typo?

Comment: Check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35526138/assign-ajax-result-to-interface-inclusive-methods/35533660#35533660. In my answer I have shown my solution to similar problem. It might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution I have found:

```
static fromJSON(json: app.domain.ItemType): app.domain.ItemType {

        var result = new ItemType();

        for (var key in json) {
            if(result.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                result[key] = json[key]
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

I have created the static method to convert JSON objects to TS objects