# Angular2 HTTP GET - Cast response into full object

Tags: typescript, angular

I have this simple Component

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouterLink, RouteParams} from 'angular2/router';
import {Http, Response, Headers} from 'angular2/http';
import {User} from '../../models/user';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Component({
    template: `
        <h1>{{user.name}} {{user.surname}}</h1>
    `,
    directives: [RouterLink],
})
export class UserComponent {

    user: User;

    constructor(private routeParams: RouteParams,
        public http: Http) {
            this.user = new User();
            this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/user/' + this.routeParams.get('id'))
                .map((res: Response) => res.json())
                .subscribe((user: User) => this.user = user);
        console.log(this.user);
    }
}
```

Why does `subscribe` not cast the response into a full `User` object. When I am logging the `user` variable my console say `User {_id: undefined, name: undefined, surname: undefined, email: undefined}`. But nevertheless binding to `.name` and `.surname` in the view is working..

What happens here? Where is the user actually stored?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I cast a JSON object to a typescript class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875636/how-do-i-cast-a-json-object-to-a-typescript-class)

Comment: I read this is a good article also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63964124/angular-convert-api-data-into-new-data-type-in-reusable-clean-method?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29759472/2854890

My Method now looks like this:

```
constructor(private routeParams: RouteParams,
    public http: Http) {
    this.user = new User();
    this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/user/' + this.routeParams.get('id'))
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .subscribe((json: Object) => {
            this.user = new User().fromJSON(json);
        });
}
```

I enhanced the `Serializable` by returning the object in the end, so I can leave out something like

```
var u = new User();
u.fromJSON(...);
```

and just write

```
new User().fromJSON(json);
```

**`Serializable`** class

```
export class Serializable {

    fromJSON(json) {
        for (var propName in json)
            this[propName] = json[propName];
        return this;
    }

}
```

Comment: In Angular 6 that map() line is giving error:
`Argument of type '(res: Response) => Promise<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Response, index: number) => Promise<any>'.`

Comment: map has changed in Angular 6. Check this out: https://academind.com/learn/angular/snippets/angular-6-whats-new-angular-upgrade/#rxjs-6-changes-operator-usage

Comment: @DanielHitzel Your original problem was that your `console.log` is executed before the response arrived. Even if it was at the correct position, you would overwrite the value in your `subscribe` handler by a plain object (`this.user = user`) which is not an instance of `User` anymore (Nevertheless a `User`-compatible object with same properties). Both problems are solved by this answer. However, I wanted to point out that your actual problem - property values are `undefined` - originated in another mistake.

Comment: looking at the code with more experience, yes that's seems to be true :D

Answer (score 25):

Good practice is to consume data from GET response using

```
Observable<Model>
```

(regarding to Angular documentation https://angular.io/guide/http)
so...

// imports

```
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
```

// in constructor parameter list

```
private http: HttpClient
```

// service method

```
getUser(): Observable<User> {return this.http.get<User>({url}, {options});}
```

You do not need to do anything more. I consider this approach as most friendly.

Comment: This will work for most approaches, but it doesn't cast, more like a type assertion.
If you have a function in your class
`export class User {
  test() {
    console.log("works");
  }
}`
You can't run user.test().

Comment: Just to avoid confusion for anyone this approach is only available in Angular 4.3+ where the new HttpClient was introduced.

Comment: @DarrenLewis , what is approach we have to use if get method wants to return array of Model?

Comment: @Anil This method works fine also for an array of Model. Just instead of User you put User[]

Comment: @ovmcit5eoivc4 No, this is not how TypeScript works. There are no runtime type checks. Most devs seem to be not even aware that their type annotated variables aren't necessarily instances of the class. For example the `hero` object in Angular's tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1#create-a-hero-class.

Comment: The author's problem is that his `log` command is executed before the response arrives. Your answer isn't related to the author's problem at all in my opionion. Furthermore he asks for a "full `User` object"  which I interpret as `User` class instance. So even if his log was at the correct possition your answer would be wrong as it will return a plain object (as ovmcit5eoivc4 pointed out above)

Comment: I logged in just to vote up your answer because it really helped me.

Comment: This casts the any object (from the response) to the Users class. This results in a Partial<User> object, which just blindly maps the properties. This isn't a full object, so this is not the answer to this question. None of the methods of the User class will work, including getters/setters, the constructor and all other methods, since they don't exist on Partial<User>

Answer (score 0):

That's not supported by TypeScript.

See [How do I cast a JSON object to a typescript class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875636/how-do-i-cast-a-json-object-to-a-typescript-class) for more details.

Comment: But why am I able to bind to the data anyway. It gets displayed, whereas the variable I am binding to is logged as undefined..
How does binding work then

Comment: JSON and object is interchangeable in TypeScript/JS but the created object will only contain what the JSON contained, but no methods or other fields that are only defined in the prototype of of the real class.

Comment: if I change this to `.subscribe(data => this.user = new User(data._id, data.name, data.surname, data.email));` the log is still the same. What do I need to log in order to get the object the view in binding to?

Comment: There is another mistake I missed. `       console.log(this.user);` is executed before the HTTP request is made. `this.http.get()` is async, which means the task is enqueued in the browser event queue for later execution, then JS execution is continued (with your log command). When the HTTP call is done, the callback passed to `.subscribe(...)` is executed, but that's much later. Move the log call into `subscribe((user: User) => { ... });`