# Where to do mapping logic for API data in Angular2 service

Tags: angular, rest, api

In my Angular2 app I have a Injectable WebcamsService. This service should get all webcams or add a new webcam.

```
....

@Injectable()
export class WebcamsService {

  constructor (private http: Http) {}

   getWebcams(id: number) {
     ...
   }


  addWebcam(...) {
    ...
  }

}
```

**The response of the API ( GET /api/v1/webcams ):**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "url": "http://www.xyz.de",
      "name": "WebcamName",
      "location": {
         "country": "XY",
         "city": "Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "url": "http://www.xyz.de",
      "name": "WebcamName",
      "location": {
         "country": "XY",
         "city": "Z"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**The response of the API (POST /api/v1/webcams):**

```
{
  "data": {
    "spot_id": "1",
    "name": "X",
    "url": "Y",
    "location": {
       "country": "XY",
       "city": "Z"
    }
  }
}
```

Now of course I want to map these responses to objects. The classes are looking like this:

**Webcam-model**

```
export class Webcam {
  id: number;
  url: string;
  name: string;
  location: Location;
}
```

**Location-model**

```
export class Location {
  country: string;
  city: string;
}
```

Now I have to map the response to my objects. I think there are several options:

- A mapping-function in the service
- Mapping in the constructor (pass json to the constructor of the model)

***Are there any more options?
Which option should I use?***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON to TypeScript class instance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29758765/json-to-typescript-class-instance)

Comment: Can't help but think you're building something naughty..