# Angular 2 model function interpolation - self.context.$implicit.X is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, string-interpolation

All,

I am getting an error when trying to bind to a function on a model

I have the following Component, Model & Html (all fake for this example)

```
export class TestModel {    
  public getSomeValue(): string {
     return "Hello World";
  }
}
```

Let's just assume the testModels property get's it's data somehow.

```
@Component(...)
public class MyComponent {    
  public testModels: TestModel[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadData();
  }

  public loadData(): void
  {
     this.http.get("...")
     .map(r=>r.json as TestModel[]) // <--- I think now you've asked the question, I see the problem on this line
     .subscribe(d=>this.testModels = d);

  }
}
```

Now in my html

```
<div *ngFor="let testModel of testModels">
  <span>{{testModel.getSomeValue()}}</span> <!-- This fails -->
</div>
```

This is the full error:

> error_handler.js:48 EXCEPTION: Error in
>   ./MyComponent class MyComponent- inline template:94:56 caused by:
>   self.context.$implicit.getSomeValue is not a function

Is is not possible to bind to `.getSomeValue()` or am I doing this wrong?

I'm assuming based on this `self.context.$implicit.` it's loosing it's context somehow and not calling the method on the model but attempting to call it on "it's self" what ever that is?

Thanks

S

EDIT: Added code to show how testModels is instantiated

Comment: How are you instantiating `testModels`?

Comment: Where does the `TestModel` instance come from? From JSON?

Comment: Yep it's actually a web service. I'll update the code example to show

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`as TestModel[]` doesn't make it a `TestModel`. It just tells the typescript compiler (and linter) that it can safely assume that `r.json` is `TestModel[]`.

See also [JSON to TypeScript class instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29758765/json-to-typescript-class-instance)

Comment: Thank you @Günter Zöchbauer

Answer (score 1):

you can add a getter to your typescript class

```
export class Person {
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
    get name(): string {
        return `${this.firstname} ${this.lastname}`;
    }
}
```