# Typescript computed getter not working

Tags: typescript, properties

This computed property `lastSeenString` used to be working for me:

```
export class User {
    public lastSeen?: Date;
    private _lastSeenString?:string = "";
    get lastSeenString():string {
        return Time.timeSince(this.lastSeen);
    }
}
```

But now `lastSeenString` returns `""`. The `return` statement in the getter is never called. How come? `lastSeen` is populated.

client:

```
it('Displays the user\'s "last seen"', () => {
    component.user.lastSeen = new Date();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.user.lastSeenString).toBe("less than a minute ago");
    expect(page.lastSeen.innerText).toBe("last seen less than a minute ago");
});
```

My typescript compiles to `es5`. Why does code inside the getter not execute?

Time class which is supposed to get executed but doesn't:

```
export class Time {
    public static timeSince(date: Date) {
        let start = +new Date();
        let elapsed = +new Date() - start;
        var seconds = Math.floor((elapsed) / 1000);

        // var seconds = Math.floor((new Date() - +date) / 1000);

        //var seconds = Math.floor(((new Date().getTime()/1000) - +date))


        var interval = Math.floor(seconds / 31536000);

        if (interval > 1) {
            return interval + " years";
        }
        interval = Math.floor(seconds / 2592000);
        if (interval > 1) {
            return interval + " months";
        }
        interval = Math.floor(seconds / 86400);
        if (interval > 1) {
            return interval + " days";
        }
        interval = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
        if (interval > 1) {
            return interval + " hours";
        }
        interval = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
        if (interval > 1) {
            return interval + " minutes";
        }
        return "less than a minute ago";
    }
}
```

actual implementation of the User class:

```
export var SERENA: User = {
   id: 1,
   lastSeenString: "",
    lastSeen: new Date("October 13, 2016 11:13:00"),
    badges: ["active User", "helper"],
    memberSince: new Date("October 13, 2014")
}
```

I see the implementation has `lastSeenString = ""`, however I thought that would trigger the getter rather than just return `""`.

**Update: I'm pretty sure it must be to do with just exporting that JSON object and calling it a `User`. I think I must have to new it up.**

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The getter is defined on the prototype of `User` - i.e. as part of the class itself. You need to build your instance using that class (e.g. with `new User()`) for the getter to work.

Currently you just build a vanilla JavaScript object, and then tell TypeScript that it's the same shape as a real User object. That passes type checking, because it *is* the same shape - reading any field on it will return values of the same type that you'd be expecting from a real User object - but that doesn't tell you anything about the underlying behaviour of those fields.

Comment: Not only the getters and setters are gone in this case but also the public methods if any. Also look at the [following answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29759472/1886308) dealing with a congruent problem. Furthermore it is a good practice not to include methods (and getters and setters) in your domain entities to avoid this problem.

Comment: @GieSpaepen While I see your point, if you only have properties (no methods) in the domain model, then that would be considered a "data class" which is a code smell and is recommended only for use in prototyping as it leads to tight coupling in larger projects.

Comment: @GieSpaepen However the answer you posted is a good solution which I think I will use for my mock data :)

Comment: this makes sense, but it also exposes a huge pain point with typecsript. how frustrating. classes just feel like syntactical sugar, what's the point of any of this

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I was getting object data from the network as JSON. Then assigned the data like this:

```
   let newUser = Object.assign(new User(), data)
```

I could access all of the public data and functions, but couldn’t access functions, getters, setters for objects inside this object. So I had no access to private data even though I could print them out.

```
   class User {
      name: string
      state: UserState
    }

   class UserState {
      private _stateInfo: string
      getter()......
    }
```

So I can access name, and can print out the data of `state`. But can’t access functions inside `state`.

The way to solve this is to initialize new `UserState` object when passing the data for `User` object.

Comment: It is not clear how you solved your issue. Isn't the solution the opposite of your initial approach? `let newUser = new User(data)`, then inside the constructor, you put your `Object.assign(this, data)`