# Java Map to JSON to Typescript Map

Tags: json, angular, typescript

on my server side I have a Java object that contains a HashMap. I want to serialize it to JSON, return it to my Angular2 client and use it as a Map/Dictionary there.

Here's the class:

```
public class FileUploadResult {
    String timestamp;
    String message;
    String status;
    HashMap<String, String> parameters;

    public FileUploadResult(String status, String message, String timestamp, HashMap parameters) {
        this.status = status;
        this.message = message;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }
```

}

Here's the JSON that I receive on the client side:

```
{"timestamp":"","message":"Test","status":"1","parameters":{"myKey":"Value","mySecondKey":"Another Value"}}
```

Here's my receiving Angular2 http call:

```
this.http.post(this.uploadURL, formData).map((res:Response) => res.json() as FileUploadResult).catch(this.handleError);
```

FileUploadResult on the client looks like this:

```
export class FileUploadResult {
    status: string;
    timestamp: string;
    message: string;
    parameters: Map<string, string>;

    constructor() {
        this.parameters = new Map<string, string>();
    }

    addParameter(key: string, value: string) {
        this.parameters.set(key, value);
    }

    getParameters() {
        return this.parameters;
    }
}
```

By using the "as FileUploadResult" in the http.map call, I expected to get an object on where I can call `result.getParameters().get("myKey")`. But that's not happening. I get an unspecified object where the only call that works is `result.parameters.myKey`. Is there a way to achieve what I want and to cast the JSON object to the FileUploadResult including the Angular2 map?

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29758765/json-to-typescript-class-instance ?

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh no unfortunately not. I do not know the keys in advance.

Answer (score 18):

The result of calling `res.json()` is a javascript object which can be accessed like so:

```
let json = res.json();
console.log(json["timestamp"]);
console.log(json.message);
```

The way to describe such an object in typescript is using an interface (or type alias):

```
interface JsonResponse {
    timestamp: string;
    message: string;
    status: string;
    parameters: { [name: string]: string };
}
```

If you want to transform this object into your class you'll need to do something like:

```
class FileUploadResult {
    status: string;
    timestamp: string;
    message: string;
    parameters: Map<string, string>;

    constructor(json: JsonResponse) {
        this.status = json.status;
        this.timestamp = json.timestamp;
        this.message = json.message;

        this.parameters = new Map<string, string>();
        Object.keys(json.parameters).forEach(key => {
            this.addParameter(key, json.parameters[key]);
        });
    }

    addParameter(key: string, value: string) {
        this.parameters.set(key, value);
    }

    getParameters() {
        return this.parameters;
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20REGISTRY%20%3D%20new%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20string%5B%5D%3E%3E()%3B%0Afunction%20register(cls%3A%20string%2C%20property%3A%20string%2C%20decorator%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20map%3A%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20string%5B%5D%3E%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(REGISTRY.has(cls))%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20map%20%3D%20REGISTRY.get(cls)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20map%20%3D%20new%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20string%5B%5D%3E()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20REGISTRY.set(cls%2C%20map)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20list%3A%20string%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(map.has(property))%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20list%20%3D%20map.get(property)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20list%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20map.set(property%2C%20list)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(list.indexOf(decorator)%20%3C%200)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20list.push(decorator)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20First()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20function%20(cls%3A%20any%2C%20property%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20register(cls.constructor.name%2C%20property%2C%20%22First%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20Second()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20function%20(cls%3A%20any%2C%20property%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20register(cls.constructor.name%2C%20property%2C%20%22Second%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Test%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%40First()%0A%20%20%20%20%40Second()%0A%20%20%20%20public%20someAttribute%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20public%20getListOfAttributeDecorators(property%3A%20string)%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20name%20%3D%20this.constructor.name%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20!REGISTRY.has(name)%20%3F%20%5B%5D%20%3A%20REGISTRY.get(name).get(property)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20t%20%3D%20new%20Test()%3B%0Alet%20names%20%3D%20t.getListOfAttributeDecorators(%22someAttribute%22)%3B%0Aconsole.log(names)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B%22Second%22%2C%20%22First%22%5D#src=const%20REGISTRY%20%3D%20new%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20string%5B%5D%3E%3E()%3B%0Afunction%20register(cls%3A%20string%2C%20property%3A%20string%2C%20decorator%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20map%3A%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20string%5B%5D%3E%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(REGISTRY.has(cls))%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20map%20%3D%20REGISTRY.get(cls)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20map%20%3D%20new%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20string%5B%5D%3E()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20REGISTRY.set(cls%2C%20map)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20list%3A%20string%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(map.has(property))%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20list%20%3D%20map.get(property)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20list%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20map.set(property%2C%20list)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(list.indexOf(decorator)%20%3C%200)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20list.push(decorator)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20First()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20function%20(cls%3A%20any%2C%20property%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20register(cls.constructor.name%2C%20property%2C%20%22First%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20Second()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20function%20(cls%3A%20any%2C%20property%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20register(cls.constructor.name%2C%20property%2C%20%22Second%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Test%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%40First()%0A%20%20%20%20%40Second()%0A%20%20%20%20public%20someAttribute%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20public%20getListOfAttributeDecorators(property%3A%20string)%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20name%20%3D%20this.constructor.name%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20!REGISTRY.has(name)%20%3F%20%5B%5D%20%3A%20REGISTRY.get(name).get(property)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20t%20%3D%20new%20Test()%3B%0Alet%20names%20%3D%20t.getListOfAttributeDecorators(%22someAttribute%22)%3B%0Aconsole.log(names)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B%22Second%22%2C%20%22First%22%5D#src=type%20StringUnion%20%3D%20string%20%7C%20string%5B%5D%3B%0Atype%20StringUnionMap%20%3D%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20StringUnion%20%7D%3B%0A%0Alet%20map1%3A%20StringUnionMap%20%3D%20%7B%20%22key1%22%3A%20%22value1%22%2C%20%22key2%22%3A%20%22value2%22%20%7D%3B%0Alet%20map2%3A%20StringUnionMap%20%3D%20%7B%20%22key3%22%3A%20%5B%22value3a%22%2C%20%22value3b%22%5D%20%7D%3B%0A%0Alet%20combinedMap%3A%20StringUnionMap%20%3D%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20map1%2C%20map2)%3B%0Aconsole.log(combinedMap)%3B#src=interface%20JsonResponse%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20timestamp%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20message%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20status%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20parameters%3A%20%7B%20%5Bname%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20FileUploadResult%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20status%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20timestamp%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20message%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20parameters%3A%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20string%3E%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(json%3A%20JsonResponse)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.status%20%3D%20json.status%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.timestamp%20%3D%20json.timestamp%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.message%20%3D%20json.message%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.parameters%20%3D%20new%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20string%3E()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.keys(json.parameters).forEach(key%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.addParameter(key%2C%20json.parameters%5Bkey%5D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20addParameter(key%3A%20string%2C%20value%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.parameters.set(key%2C%20value)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20getParameters()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.parameters%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D))

Answer (score 1):

```
 class FileUploadResult {
    parameters: Record<string, string> = {};

    addParameter(key: string, value: string) {
       this.parameters[key] = value;
    }
}
```

You can use it this way

```
const abc = new FileUploadResult();
abc.addParameter('hi', 'hello');
console.log(abc.parameters);   // will log {hi: "hello"}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt