# Javascript Object Keys Not Resolved Until After console.log Is Expanded

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am having the same issue as [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546953/cant-access-object-property-even-though-it-exists-returns-undefined). While that question was answered, a resolution was not provided.

I have a javascript object where console.log(anObject) shows all of the keys, but console.log(JSON.stringify(anObject)) does not show them all, it only shows 1 of the 2.

What is the cause of this at the javascript (not console) level and how can I resolve this so that the code that follows this segment can access all of the keys?

Is there a way to force object resolution?

Thanks in advance.

---

It is wrapped inside of a getJson which is asynchronous, but ironically the data being left out is not the json result data. I'm using the cytoscape.js library. The problem occurs around line 5183 of the cytoscape.js file in this section where it is parsing my xar (elements array) as shown below. The data key is there, but not the group key unless it is expended in console.

```
      // specify via opts.nodes and opts.edges
  else if( $$.is.plainObject(opts) && ($$.is.array(opts.nodes) || $$.is.array(opts.edges)) ){
    var elesByGroup = opts;
    var jsons = [];

    var grs = ['nodes', 'edges'];
    for( var i = 0, il = grs.length; i < il; i++ ){
      var group = grs[i];
      var elesArray = elesByGroup[group];

      if( $$.is.array(elesArray) ){

        for( var j = 0, jl = elesArray.length; j < jl; j++ ){
              //console.log(JSON.stringify(elesArray[j]))
          if ( typeof elesArray[j] !== "undefined" ) {
              var json = elesArray[j];
              console.log(elesArray[j].data)
              json.group = group;
              jsons.push( json );
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

---

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 function notInArray(value, array) {
     return array.indexOf(value) == -1;
 }

 var node_array = new Array();
 var edge_array = new Array();

 var full_data;

 var xar = new Object();

 xar.nodes = [];
 xar.edges = [];

 $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1/loctest", function(xad) {
     full_data = xad;
     var i = 0;
     $.each(xad, function(key, val) {
         s = val.src;
         d = val.dst;
         if (notInArray(s, node_array)) {
             node_array.push(s);
             xar.nodes[i] = {
                 data: {
                     id: s
                 }
             };
             i++;
         }
         if (notInArray(d, node_array)) {
             node_array.push(d);
             xar.nodes[i] = {
                 data: {
                     id: d
                 }
             };
         }
         xar.edges[i] = {
             data: {
                 id: i.toString(),
                 weight: 3,
                 source: s,
                 target: d
             }
         };
         i++;
     });

     //console.log(xar);
     $('#cy').cytoscape({
         //container: document.getElementById('cy'),

         style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
             .selector('node')
             .css({
                 'content': 'data(id)'
             })
             .selector('edge')
             .css({
                 'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
                 'width': 4,
                 'line-color': '#ddd',
                 'target-arrow-color': '#ddd'
             })
             .selector('.highlighted')
             .css({
                 'background-color': '#61bffc',
                 'line-color': '#61bffc',
                 'target-arrow-color': '#61bffc',
                 'transition-property': 'background-color, line-color, target-arrow-color',
                 'transition-duration': '0.5s'
             }),

         elements: xar,

         layout: {
             name: 'breadthfirst',
             directed: true,
             roots: '#a',
             padding: 10
         }
     });


     console.log(cy);
     var bfs = cy.elements().bfs('#a', function() {}, true);

     var p = 0;
     var highlightNextEle = function() {
         bfs.path[p].addClass('highlighted');

         if (p < bfs.path.length) {
             p++;
             setTimeout(highlightNextEle, 1000);
         }
     };

     // kick off first highlight
     highlightNextEle();

 });

});
```

Comment: Can you put here enough code to reproduce your problem ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Code snippet added - my apologies for not adding it sooner. I wasn't sure if this was a generic variable object key issue or something that could be specific to this particular code. Hence my only referencing the other SO article at first.

Comment: Hi Eli how did you solve your issue? were you able to force the resolution of the object?

Comment: No, I ended up refactoring the javascript to handle the AJAX call differently in order to ensure that all variables were populated fully before the workflow continued.

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.stringify` only lists enumerable own properties.

This is explained in [15.12.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.12.3):

> The abstract operation *JO*(*value*) serializes an object.
>
> Let *K* be an internal List of Strings consisting of the names of all
>   the own properties of *value* whose [[Enumerable]] attribute is
>   **true**. The ordering of the Strings should be the same as that used by the **Object.keys** standard built-in function.

So if you don't see the property, it can mean

- The property has not been added yet. Note `console.log` may be asynchroneous, so the property might be added after calling `log` but be displayed in the console
- The property is inherited instead of own
- The property is not enumerable

Comment: As per the other so question that I referenced, I'm only using JSON.stringify to demonstrate that the key isn't there yet. I'm having trouble determining WHY the key isn't there yet since the asynchronous data is there, but this key which is added shortly before in the code isn't.