# Printing individual objects to a DOM when their IDs vary

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, spotify

I am working on a JavaScript web app that takes input from a user (the name of a musical artist) and outputs a list of related artists and their most popular song, as determined by the Spotify API. I initially had a rudimentary version of this functioning, but it would just post a list of all the related artists with a list of those related artists' most popular songs immediately above it, and I want the entire object to print out (artist plus most popular song).

I have a series of objects representing the artists that I received through the [spotify-web-api-js](https://github.com/JMPerez/spotify-web-api-js) node module with Node.js and Browserify to make it function on the browser, uniquely identified by their Spotify ID. How can I loop through them if I don't know those IDs in advance before a user does a search so that I can properly push them into an object that I can then input to the DOM through jQuery's `append`? I've been trying to access them in various ways, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
s.getArtistRelatedArtists(originalArtistId, function(err, data) {

  for (i = 0; i < data.artists.length; i++)
  {
      console.log(data.artists[i].name);
      relatedArtistsObject[data.artists[i].id] = {
        name: data.artists[i].name,
        songs: []
      };
      s.getArtistTopTracks(data.artists[i].id, "US", function (err, data2) {
          if (relatedArtistsObject[data2.tracks[0].artists[0].id] !== undefined)
          {
          // console.log(data2.tracks[0].name); -- this outputs the song titles I want
            relatedArtistsObject[data2.tracks[0].artists[0].id].songs.push(data2.tracks[0].name);

          }
      });
  }
 console.log(relatedArtistsObject);
 // loop through this object and print it through the screen
 for (k = 0; k < relatedArtistsObject.length; k++)
 {

   console.log(relatedArtistsObject.id.songs[0].name);
   $('#related-artist').append(relatedArtistsObject[k]);

 }
  //  $('#related-artist').append(relatedArtistsObject);
 });
```

Here is a link to the full code (not functioning because it doesn't have Node.js/browserify enabled): https://jsfiddle.net/pmh04e99/

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31952281) is partially helpful, but doesn't apply here because the JSON output doesn't have a "name" field in the array I want to access. Instead, `songs` is an array of 1, and the content I want is within item `0`. My console.log output of the `relatedArtistsObject` looks like this, for example:

[image]

How can I access these objects in the DOM through my code when I don't know the spotify IDs right now?

Note: I'm aware that i'm not error handling yet, but I want to be able to implement the main functionality first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) or use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

The former will iterate over each enumerable property name of the object, and setting that name into the specified variable. You can then use that name to access that object's property value.

The latter will return an array of the object's property names. You can then use a regular for loop to iterate over that array and use each of the values in the array as the id

For...In

```
for(id in relatedArtistsObject){
  var artist = relatedArtistsObject[id];
  console.log(artist.name,artist.songs);
}
```

Object.keys

```
var ids = Object.keys(relatedArtistsObject);
for(var i=0; i<ids.length; i++){
  var artist = relatedArtistsObject[ids[i]];
  console.log(artist.name,artist.songs);   
}
```

Comment: Both the Object.keys and For...In gave me the artist name with an empty array `[ ]`. Since the `songs` array has one item in it, I tried `artist.songs[0]`, and that gave me `undefined` with each. I'll continue to look into it, but is there anything you suggest for that issue? Thanks!

Comment: turns out it was an `async.times` issue; it was calling for the artist's top song before the last JSON request for the related artists was complete, which is why it was undefined. I'm going to accept your answer because you solved the actual question I asked, and it was helpful with getting me on the right path.