# How do I access `status` from this `object` being shown in console?

Tags: javascript, jquery

`index.html` is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    $( document ).ready(function() {

        var obj = $.get('tmp.html');
        console.log(obj);
        console.log('obj.status:'+obj.status); 


    });

    </script>    
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Output in `console` is:

[image]

Question is how do I access that `status` code which is to `200`, the way I am doing it shows it's undefined though it's `200`

[Code on plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/iKlWybiHnWzlrHyb4ZSq?p=preview)

Comment: The reason it doesn't work in its current state is that you are accessing it before the request finishes. Why do you need to access the status directly if you are using jQuery? The object has built in callbacks for a reason. You should use success, done, always, or fail, or any number of other options rather than directly accessing it.

Comment: Some info here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17547032/1336342

Comment: Note that little blue `i` - the tooltip for it says something along the lines of the object being re-evalutated when you expand the properties - ie it's (potentially) different from the moment it got logged.

Comment: You are accessing it wrong way. use success callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the state of the `jqXHR` object is updated to include `status` **after** your call to `console.log()`. this is nature of asynchronous actions in JavaScript.

$.get() returns a `jqXHR` object as per [this](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR). You need to chain a callback function such as `done()` to get access to the status code, which will be passed in to your callback function.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this --

```
$.get("tmp.html", function(data, status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
});
```

or if you want the complete status then try this --

```
$.get("tmp.html", function(data, status){

}).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log(jqXHR.status  )
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to get response code is given below

```
$.ajax({
//...        
success: function(data, status, response) {
    console.log(response.status);
},
complete: function(response, status) {
    console.log(response.status);
}
```