# JavaScript property duplicates [dot vs bracket]…

Tags: javascript

I have an issue where I try to count combinations. I try to solve it with JavaScript, but have some issues... Example for the different sets:

```
var colors    = ["Yellow", "Blue"];
var decisions = ["Yes", "No"];
```

As a first step I create an *empty* object and try to fill it with the two arrays and initialize a counter for each combination:

```
var myObject = {};
for ( colorIndex in colors ) {
   myObject[colors[colorIndex]] = {};
   for ( decisionIndex in decisions ) {
      myObject[color][decisions[decisionIndex]] = 0;
   }
}
```

In a next step I try to count results I got - Example:

```
var color = "Yellow";
var decision = "Yes";
myObject[color][decision] += 1;
```

**Debugging** (what I tried)

However, the result I am getting is something like:

```
Yellow: {Yes: 0, No: 0, Yes: NaN}
```

When I try to debug whats happening then I make the observation that the variables shortcodes are as follows:

```
myObject.Yellow.Yes    = 0
myObject.Yellow.No     = 0
myObject.Yellow["Yes"] = NaN
```

At this point I am not sure if I left away anything important, but does anyone of you know whats going on? I thought the brackets and dot-notation *should* be equivalent, even though I don't know how the dot-notation has been created here, since **Yes** and **No** were strings...

Can you pinpoint me in a direction?

Thanks for reading this.

### Edit: Change to forEach-loop:

Based on recommendations I changed the loop to:

```
var myObject = {};
colors.forEach(function(color) {
   myObject[color] = {};
   decisions.forEach(function(decision) {
      myObject[color][decision] = 0;
   });
});
```

However, the problem remains that I get the `NaN`-case

Comment: Is it only the count of combinations you want to get or do you also want to have the arrays combined?

Comment: Do not use `for..in` to iterate an array. Please see [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript).

Comment: the code you supply isn't valid. when you do `for item in arr` the item will be the indexes of the array

Comment: Note that you should not use *for..in* over arrays as you may not get properties in the order you expect and you may get other properties.

Comment: I'm going to switch to the forEach and let you know how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## With stringify - A hidden line-break.

I continued reading and found [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546953/cant-access-object-property-even-though-it-exists-returns-undefined).

By stringify-ing my two inputs `color` and `decision` I noticed that they are not "equal" in a way they seemed by just logging it to the console, it turns out that one of them had a line-break in it (`\r`)...

```
JSON.stringify(color)
> "\"Yellow"\"

JSON.stringify(decision)
> "\"Yes\r\""
```

*I know that, that was not clear from how I asked the question, and my example would not have allowed you to reveal that.*

I'm going to do some research on how to get rid of that, but I think it should be fairly simple.

Sorry my question wasn't that clear, but I did not expect that this was the reason. Thank you very much for your help though. Very appreciated!

Comment: great... you found the root cause

Answer (score 2):

i modify your code as bellow, and works fine , the problem is the way you use `for in`
also you have wrong code on `for ( decisions in decision )` that should be `for ( decision in decisions )`

```
var colors    = ["Yellow", "Blue"];
var decisions = ["Yes", "No"];

var myObject = {};
for ( color in colors ) {
   myObject[colors[color]] = {};
   for ( decision in decisions ) {
      myObject[colors[color]][decisions[decision]] = 0;
   }
}

var color = "Yellow";
var decision = "Yes";
myObject[color][decision] += 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. That's exactly what I have in my code, but when I generalized it, to post it here, I did that silly mistake again.

Answer (score 1):

Dude, typo error in your second loop. You have written

```
decisions in decision
```

Whereas, it should be

```
decision in decisions
```

Everything ia fine.

Comment: Thanks! That's not the actual problem I have, I just posted that part wrong here. I fixed it, but my Problem with two "yes" still remains... :/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var myObject = {};
colors.forEach(function(color){
myObject[color] = {};
 decisions.forEach(function(decision){
   myObject[color][decision] = 0;
  })
})
```

As **colors** and **decisions** are arrays, you should not use for-in to loop through

Comment: I'm going to try that and let you know if it resolves the issue.

Comment: It wasn't that issue, but thank you for your input! (See my Answer for what it was.. - it was very stupid -.-')