# Property '_body' does not exist on type 'Response'

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I am using Angular 2 and getting this error when using an observable `Property '_body' does not exist on type 'Response'`.   The code is below

```
this.securitiesService.getMarketMovers()
    .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(JSON.parse(data._body))
    });
```

The getMarketMovers function is simply this:

```
getMarketMovers() {
    return this._http.get('...url address...')
}
```

I have tried to set `data` to type `any` but that isn't working for me.  The code works and there is definitely a `_body` property on data but it still throws there error and I cant build with this error.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: show `getMarketMovers` method code.

Comment: Try `data.json()._body`

Comment: You getting an run-time error or compile-time error? Sounds for me like an compile-time error, so you have to cast that `data` variable to your correct type. Or your `getMarketMovers` function should be return the correct type!

Comment: Thanks!  I put `:any` after my getMarketMovers function `getMarketMovers(): any` and it works

Answer (score 80):

**UPDATE**

Another way, is to explicitly tell TypeScript that we’re not interested in doing strict type checking.

```
(<any>data)._body
```

**ORIGINAL**

This `data["_body"]` should work.

Comment: This helped me in almost exact same situation. Thanks!

Comment: this looks like a hack IMHO, is there better way to check if a Response has empty body?

Comment: This is the only way I could make it work, thank you! :)

Comment: Wow, for anyone looking to fix problems like not being able to access properties coming back from a call, this is your answer! confounded typescript! i read all kinds of stuff like this, but its just Typescript! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546953/cant-access-object-property-even-though-it-exists-returns-undefined

Comment: After 1h... finding this... me like [this](https://media.giphy.com/media/xULW8y5CDynhoSOwVy/giphy.gif). Thanks a lot!

Comment: I went for the original because it seems way cleaner. Thank you.

Comment: You can also use `(data as any)._body` incase you have a [forbidden angle bracket assertion](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-angle-bracket-type-assertion/)

Answer (score 19):

```
data.json();
```

will give you the json result:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html

Answer (score 2):

to solve this error better way would be to add.
: Promise <any> after getMarketMovers() function.