# Returns undefined on a object prop even though it exists-JS

Tags: javascript, json

I'm having the same issue as mentioned here: [Can't access object property, even though it exists. Returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546953/cant-access-object-property-even-though-it-exists-returns-undefined)

However in my case it's a property with `data.hostId.id`, where `data` comes in as full object and `hostId` is shown undefined when its actually present in the json object, here's how it looks:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, I'm trying to access the `qgUSerHost`(at the very end) from the object and it throws undefined. I tried `setTimeout`, not working…

I also tried the solution mentioned in that post but nothing helped.
Any ideas on this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should access that property like `this.hostAsset["qgUserHost.id"]` because of the `.` in the property name, so it wouldn't try to access the property `id` from some `qgUserHost` object.

Answer (score 1):

'this.hostAsset.qgUserHost.id' != 'this.hostAsset.qgUserHost'