# Angular2 - .subscribe() returning undefined (sometimes)

Tags: angular

I'm finding my way through Angular 2, but I'm having a little trouble understanding the results that I'm getting from `console.log` when calling `.subscribe` within `ngOnInit()`.  (Apologies in advance - I have practically zero experience with Angular and I am trying to jump into the middle of someone else's project - please forgive me if I do not quite explain this correctly)

In brief summary, if I `console.log(this)`, I get an object with a `members` property that is an array - however, if I `console.log(this.members)`, I get `undefined`.

In `group-form.component.ts`, I call

```
ngOnInit() {
     this.memberService.getMembers().subscribe(
         members => this.members = members.map(x => new Member(x))
         error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
         () => console.log(this))
};
```

And, pleasingly, this logs

```
GroupFormComponent
    model: Group
    members: Array[5]
    memberService: MemberService
    submitData: EventEmitter
    submitted: false
    __proto__: Object
```

However, if I change it to log `this.members` like so:

```
ngOnInit() {
     this.memberService.getMembers().subscribe(
         members => this.members = members.map(x => new Member(x))
         error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
         () => console.log(this.members))
};
```

this logs `undefined`.

I'm not sure that I understand why this is happening, since the `log` is being called at the same place in the chain of events.  Why should `.members` have content when viewed as part of the object, but be `undefined` when viewed on its own?

And how can I get it to set and log the correct values?

Comment: That's not angular issue. There are multiple reasons this could be happening and you don't give enough information to actually know what's wrong so I recommend to just go through answers here and see what works for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546953/cant-access-object-property-even-though-it-exists-returns-undefined

Comment: @Erndob ok thank you, will check that out.