# value undefined when push use angular 2 ts

Tags: angular

i can get 'sm' in console.log result before push it,
but got undefined when try to push.

```
chooseMenu(menu:Menuitems){
const sm = {name:menu.name,quantity:1,price:menu.product[('price')]}
console.log("item add",sm);
this.choosenMenu.push(sm); 
}
```

'price' become undefined, please guide so i can push 'sm'.

here is data response **menu:MenuItems**

```
 {
  "data": {
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "Canadian Wrap",
        "product": {
          "price": 6.99
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Chicken Caesar Wrap",
        "product": {
          "price": 5.75
        }
      },
```

and result console log for 'sm'

```
name:"Caramel Sundae"
 price:2.99
 quantity:1
```

i have no access to do

```
menu.product.price
```

or

```
menu.product[0].price
```

how to make sure "price" not become undefined so i can push it,
 thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't access object property, even though it exists. Returns undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546953/cant-access-object-property-even-though-it-exists-returns-undefined)

Comment: Can you provide us with the error message you receive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for Guide @AJT_82 and John help to resolve it, event i still can`t get clear understanding about this two ways binding angular 2, here  resolve code i did:

```
chooseMenu(menu:Menuitems){
 if(typeof menu.product == "string") {
   menu.product = JSON.stringify(menu.product) // this first, then you can parse it!
   menu.product = JSON.parse(menu.product) // then parse it...
 }
 const sm = {name:menu.name,quantity:1,price:menu.product[('price')]}
 console.log("item add",sm);
 this.choosenMenu.push(sm); 
}
```

for me only menu.product need to stringify and parse and

```
price:menu.product[('price')]
```

still need i think that angular 2 ways

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `menu.product[('price')]`, try `menu.product.price` or `menu.product["price"]`.

if your price is `undefined` to begin with, it will be `undefined` in your object as well. Maybe the price will be defined in the object later in the program, thus the `console.log()` is displaying the price (similar behaviour as [the possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546953/cant-access-object-property-even-though-it-exists-returns-undefined)).

EDIT: after some more information, it seems like you are receiving a string instead of an object. You have to make sure that the item is an object before accessing variables. You should use a `JSON.parse(yourString)` to convert it to an object.

```
chooseMenu(menu:Menuitems){
 if(typeof menu == "string") menu = JSON.parse(menu); // preferably do this when initializing menu.
 const sm = {name:menu.name,quantity:1,price:menu.product.price}
 console.log("item add",sm);
 this.choosenMenu.push(sm); 
}
```

> Also, I would change the object type of `Menuitems` to `Menu` for
>   readability. It is not clear wether or not the `menu`-object is a list
>   or not. If it is a list, I would change the type to `Array<Menu>`, and then change the method accordingly.

Comment: i  can`t type   menu.product.price or menu.product[0].price is not accessable

Comment: What do you mean by having no access? You get an error in your IDE, saying that it is not accessable?

Comment: if i use  menu.product.price  the error: "property 'price' does not exist on type string ",  if using menu.product["price"] the errror: "can not read property 'price' of undefined ", i also try JSON parse and JSON stringfy just like link you provide, the result still same

Comment: If it is a string, you should do a  `JSON.parse()` instead of `JSON.stringify()`, and then try to access the properties.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the comments and your error msg, i.e:

> if i use menu.product.price the error: "property 'price' does not exist on type string ", if using menu.product["price"] the errror: "can not read property 'price' of undefined "

It looks indeed as at you are dealing with a string. So John is on the right track here with JSON.parse. But if you are dealing with a string, you can't actually parse it directly before stringifying it, so just do:

```
chooseMenu(menu:Menuitems){
 if(typeof menu == "string") {
   menu = JSON.stringify(menu) // this first, then you can parse it!
   menu = JSON.parse(menu) // then parse it...
 }
 const sm = {name:menu.name,quantity:1,price:menu.product.price}
 console.log("item add",sm);
 this.choosenMenu.push(sm); 
}
```