# On IE11 I cant go into a object/array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer, object

I have an object called data. Within this object there is another object (or array, I'm not sure....), called maps. To reach maps I just do data.maps and this works on all browsers except for IE. When I `console.log(data);` i get this:

```
{
    "maps": [{
        "Media_Map_Id": "55",
        "Media_Id": "657"
    }]
}
```

When I `console.log(data.maps);` it says undefined....

I also got this error, it might have something to do with it eventhough I already fixed it.

```
Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference
```

code:

```
    if(data.maps) {
        dMapsLength = data.maps.length;
    } else {
        dMapsLength = 0;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < dMapsLength; i++) {
        createVars(data.maps[i], i);
    }
```

SOLVED (credits to evolutionxbox):

```
  if (typeof(data) !== 'object') {
       data = JSON.parse(data);
   }
```

Comment: should it not be data[0]

Comment: @krisph console.log(data[0]); returns a bracket "{"

Comment: @krisph no `data` is not an array.

Comment: try `data['maps']`

Comment: @MikeLammers you have to parse the json first. Use `JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: @raksaeng console.log(data['maps']); returns undefined

Comment: can we see your whole code?

Comment: This could be a duplicate of:<br/>
**Can't access object property, even though it exists. Returns undefined**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17547032/4876771 Please check it and mark this accordingly.

Comment: use this before accessing: data = JSON.parse(data);

Comment: Open developer tools and put break point on first row of your result to see the data object. Check if data object is json string and use JSON.parse(data). If it json object, so check what the structure of this object to access parameters in right way

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thanks it works now. But why does it work without JSON.parse on normal browsers but not on IE ?

Comment: maybe something wrong with AJAX on IE, when you use it