# I can't access object inside array even though it exists

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

This method stores JSON objects retrieved from a firebase database to array scores.

```
function loadScoresToArray(){
    databaseRef.orderByChild("Score").on("child_added", function (snap) {
        scores.push(snap.val());
    });
}
```

Run the above method and print content of scores

```
loadScoresToArray();
console.log(scores);

console.log(scores[0]);
```

**output**

[image]

As seen here, objects have correctly been added to scores.

But I can't retrieve them using index.

Reading similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546953/cant-access-object-property-even-though-it-exists-returns-undefined) I think this might be because when `console.log(scores[0]);` is called, the array is still empty. It has not been populated yet. This is just my guess.

How do I solve this? Is there a way to create a delay until the array is populated?

Comment: Can you access scores in global scope ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I can't retrieve them using index.

That's because you're performing an **asynchronous** operation. Instead of waiting for the `response`, the **execution** continues immediately and the statement after the request call is execute.

> How do I solve this? Is there a way to create a delay until the array
>   is populated?

No, don't use a delay. You can use a `callback` function.

```
function loadScoresToArray(callback){
    databaseRef.orderByChild("Score").on("child_added", function (snap) {
        scores.push(snap.val());
        callback(scores);
    });
}

loadScoresToArray(function(scores){
  console.log(scores[0]);
});
```

Another solution is to use `Promise` constructor in order to perform an **asynchronous** operation.

```
function loadScoresToArray(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        databaseRef.orderByChild("Score").on("child_added", function (snap){
           scores.push(snap.val());
           resolve(scores);
        });
    });
}

loadScoresToArray().then(function(scores){
     console.log(scores[0]);
});
```

Here are possible approaches in order to solve your problem.

- **Promises with async/await** (`ES2017+`)
- **Callbacks**
- **Promises with then()** (`ES2015+`)