# Chrome Copy Function Only Copies First Object Property

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to copy to my clipboard a value I saved as a global variable in Chrome's console. If I try to copy the saved global, or JSON.stringify it, I only get the first property `isTrusted`.

[image]

Comment: get all properties from MouseEvent and copy your own object

Comment: Same happens in Safari

Comment: Apparently the object logged in the console isn't the actual object -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546953/cant-access-object-property-even-though-it-exists-returns-undefined

Comment: As noted in the first comment you need to make a copy yourself or by using a js library, more info: [How to stringify event object?](//stackoverflow.com/q/11547672)

Comment: I think the other properties are omitted because they are read-only.  AFAIK this is standard behavior.  You can test this behavior:  `var obj = {x:5}; Object.defineProperty(obj, "prop", { value: "test" }); JSON.stringify(obj);`