# Why can't I read properties from a JSON cookie in express, when I see them in the console?

Tags: express

I have the following code in express middleware...

```
const cert = req.cookies.Thing
console.log(` cookie is`, cert);
console.log("We got a cookie! "+ cert.property_a);
```

but the console shows...

```
 cookie is {"property_a":"blah","scope":"thing"}
 We got a cookie! undefined
```

If it is there, why can't I access the property? I even tried the JSON.parse(JSON.stringify) hack but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the answer is although it displays like a JSON object it is a string. I solved this by using [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values). This showed me a bunch of commas and I realized it wasn't getting parsed as JSON. Still trying to figure that last part out.

```
Object.values(cert)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful, if the issue is because of lazy resolving like promise.

[Can't access object property, even though it exists. Returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546953/cant-access-object-property-even-though-it-exists-returns-undefined)