# console.log() displays the correct value, but when assigned it to a variable, it is undefined - Angular, firestore

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, promise, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on an Angular application and want to get some data from Firestore. But my function always returns `undefined`. When I, however, `console.log()` the value before returning it, it displays the correct value.

```
getToken(user_id) {
    this.afs.collection("tokens").ref.doc(user_id).get().then((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        console.log(doc.data().user_token); //displays the correct user_token value
        return doc.data().user_token; //returns undefined!
      }
    });
}
```

Shouldn't both values be the same?

Comment: You aren't returning the actual promise. Put a `return` in front of `this.afs.collection("tokens")`. Also please show how you are consuming `getToken()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are not returning the `Promise` from your function - there is no return statement in the `getToken` function at all, so the function itself just returns `undefined`. The internal return statement you have will resolve the promise, which is good, but you have to handle that resolution.

If you return the promise like so:

```
getToken(user_id) {
    return this.afs.collection("tokens").ref.doc(user_id).get().then((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        console.log(doc.data().user_token); //displays the correct user_token value
        return doc.data().user_token;
      }
    });
}
```

You should be able to access the `user_token` asynchronously when the promise resolves by doing the following:

```
getToken(user_id).then(user_token => {
  handle_user_token_here(user_token);
});
```

*Note*: The function as modified will return a promise. Therefore, you cannot simply the following:

```
let user_token = getToken(user_id);
// user_token here is a Promise object, not the token!
handle_user_token_here(user_token); // will not work.
```

You can do this though:

```
let user_token = getToken(user_id);
// user_token here is a Promise object, not the token!
user_token.then(user_token => handle_user_token_here(user_token)); // will work
```

Comment: I tried this: `getToken(user_id).then(user_token => {
      let token = user_token.data.user_token;
    });` but when I log token, it still returns undefined

Comment: Where did you log the token? If you did this: `getToken(user_id).then(user_token => { let token = user_token.data.user_token; console.log(token); });` it should work (assuming you modified `getToken` by adding the return statement). If you did this: `getToken(user_id).then(user_token => { let token = user_token.data.user_token; });  console.log(token);` you would be trying to use `token` outside the function scope and that won't work.

Comment: I actually did this: `token:any; signInSuccess() {
    this.tokenService.getToken(user_id).then((user_token) => {
      this.token = user_token.data().user_token;
    });
    console.log(this.token);
  }` (Everything inside the HomePage class in a home.page.ts file)

Comment: And yes, I did modify `getToken()` the way way you suggested

Comment: That still won't work, as `getToken` (and any function involving promises) is asynchronous. You are accessing `this.token` after assigning it in the code, but not after the `Promise` resolves. The `Promise`could take several seconds to resolve, and in order to not stop all your code while waiting for a request to finish, the code continues immediately.

Comment: Here's an example that explains it better than I can https://jsfiddle.net/6eq7ndxu/. Run the code and open your browser console and note what order the log statements appear and with what payloads.

Answer (score 0):

This may answer your question: [Can't access object property, even though it exists. Returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546953/cant-access-object-property-even-though-it-exists-returns-undefined)

"The output of console.log(anObject) is misleading; the state of the object displayed is only resolved when you expand the > in the console."

In other words, doc.data().user_token might be getting populated by an asynchronous process.