# react array state is getting cleared before getting rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Having a response issue.

When making an ajax call to retrieve data from the backend i retrieve the data, but it appears that it retrieves the data **only** if its wrapped in a `.then()`. Outside of a `.then()` then the data clears out.

consume is a personal module that handles axios calls.

here is the issue

```
componentWillMount() {
    const retrieveLogs = {
      method: "GET",
      url: this.state.url, 
    }
    consume.fetch(retrieveLogs)
      .then(res => {
        if(typeof res.logger === "object"){
          this.setState({
            logs: res.logger,

         })
         console.log(this.state.logs) // show the console log here but
        }
    })
    console.log(this.state.logs) // but shows empty array here why is this ?
  }
```

Comment: I think it's running the second console.log before state is finished setting.

Comment: i think so too, this issue would not be good if i was mapping the data to a list. So whats will be the best approach ?

Comment: Can you put the .map logic as a callback to the promise res?

Comment: can you provide an answer demonstrating what you mean by that. im sorry

Comment: So you're using `consume` that depends on `axios` to make a fetch? Why not simply use the native [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)?

Comment: i figured it out thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Comment: @NinoFiliu that's completely irrelevant here.

Comment: @BARNOWL it looks like you're confused because of the async nature of JS, on top of the async nature of `setState`. In addition to the confusion caused by the [lazy evaluation of the console](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17547032/1218980) which makes it looks like it's there, but really wasn't when executed initially.

Comment: And the reason why the last log is empty: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1218980

Answer (score 2):

`componentWillMount` is UNSAFE and deprecated, you should not use it, see details [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html).
The best approach to is to use `componentDidMount` to fetch your data and then update the state. The initial render with an empty state is pattern, and you should not worry about it. Also you should not log your state like that, remember, `setState` is assynchronous and you have no guarantees that the state will be updated when calling `console.log`, in this cases use the second argument of `setState` which provides you a callback that only get's fired when all updates are finished.

```
componentDidMount() {
const retrieveLogs = {
  method: "GET",
  url: this.state.url, 
}
consume.fetch(retrieveLogs)
  .then(res => {
    if(typeof res.logger === "object"){
      this.setState({
        logs: res.logger,

     }, console.log(this.state.logs))

    }
})}
```

If you need to perform some operation after data arrive, use `componentDidUpdate` to implement your custom logic whenever props or state changes.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
   if(prevProps.item !== this.props.item)
       this.setState({item}, console.log(this.state.item))
}
```

Comment: You're missing the callback as the second argument, like this `this.setState({item}, () => console.log(this.state.item))`

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

I can use [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate), so that way when its completely done rendering in componentDidupdate i can then render the response data.

So if `show === false`, hence if state is rendered. then i show data, if not render null.

here is what i came up with.

```
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
    if(this.state.logs.length !== 0 && prevProps.logs === null){
      this.setState({
        show:false 
      })
    }
    console.log(this.state.logs); // shows here
  }


return(
  {!this.state.show ? (  
     <Logs logs= {this.state.logs} />  // renders the data.
  ):(
     null
   )}
)
```