# How to fix "TypeError: posters[0] is undefined" in react render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my function I can map through my list from the state but when I want to map in render it doesn't work

```js
class DesktopList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {        
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: [
                "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/S/cmx-images-prod/Item/765356/765356._SX1280_QL80_TTD_.jpg",
                "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/S/cmx-images-prod/Item/232863/232863._SX1280_QL80_TTD_.jpg",
                "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/S/cmx-images-prod/Item/779028/779028._SX1280_QL80_TTD_.jpg",
                "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/S/cmx-images-prod/Item/765281/765281._SX1280_QL80_TTD_.jpg",
                "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/S/cmx-images-prod/Item/495991/495991._SX1280_QL80_TTD_.jpg",
                "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/S/cmx-images-prod/Item/694446/694446._SX1280_QL80_TTD_.jpg",
                "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/S/cmx-images-prod/Item/460929/460929._SX1280_QL80_TTD_.jpg",
                "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/S/cmx-images-prod/Item/755543/755543._SX1280_QL80_TTD_.jpg",
                "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/S/cmx-images-prod/Item/756917/756917._SX1280_QL80_TTD_.jpg",
            ],
            posters: []
        }
    }

sortIntoArray = () => {
        let posterImages = [...this.state.items];
        const size = 5;

        const result = this.state.posters;
        for (var i=0;i<posterImages.length;i+=size)
        result.push( posterImages.slice(i,i+size) )
        this.setState({posters: result})
        let images = this.state.posters

        images[0].map(item => console.log(item.poster))
    }

render() {
        let {posters} = this.state;
        let poster = posters[0].map((item, index) => 
        <img src={item.poster} alt="poster" style={style.poster} key={index}/>
        )

return (
                <div 
                 style={style.posterList} className="posterlist">
                    {poster}
                </div>
          );
    }
}
```

I want every poster to show from the first array

this is what I get

TypeError: posters[0] is undefined

Comment: What does the structure of `posters` look like? `posters[0]` being undefined means that `posters` is likely an empty list.

Comment: I don't think it's empty because if I change posters[0] to posters it output the two arrays that's in posters but I only want to show the array with index 0and that's when it says it's undefined.

Comment: @Jonon you're falling into the second trap of JS, the console, [which shows values that weren't really available when first logged](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17546953/1218980).

Comment: So it's not actually there? but what should I think because the array.map actually output the two arrays. It's just when I try to chose index it can't. I'm confused.

Comment: We would need a [mcve] to be able to spot the underlying problem.

Comment: Added how the state looks

Comment: I fixed the problem. Instead of using posters[0] I hade to put the index in quotes. It works but I don't really understand why

Answer (score -1):

Before you do **let {posters} = this.state;** you need to call your **sortIntoArray()**, which you don't. You need to make sure that the values you're assigning from are populated (be it the state or anything else). However, from your code state.posters is undefined hence your variable posters is undefined.

It's hard to give you an exact recipe for it depends on the entirety of your component.

Comment: Even if called before, the `setState` function is async, so it'll still fail with `posters[0] is undefined`.

Comment: It depends on where you call it from. If it's called on ComponentDidRender, Render will get called after the state is updated and it will not fail.

Comment: `ComponentDidRender` doesn't even exists.

Comment: I meant componentDidMount.

Comment: Same problem, [`componentDidMount` is called after `render`](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/).

Comment: You are correct. But it doesn't matter in the context of the question. They need to make sure that their state is populated before they use it. How they do that is up to them. They can ask another question....

Comment: OP needs to make sure that his render function works when `posters` is an empty array, regardless of when the state or the data itself is available.