# Console log not printing HTML element

Tags: javascript, html

I selected objects by class name

```
var inp = document.getElementsByClassName("tagsinput field is-grouped is-grouped-multiline input");
```

but in my file, there is only one element with that class, so I tried to console.log it

```
console.log(inp);
```

and it returned:

```
HTMLCollection []
length: 1
0: div.tagsinput.field.is-grouped.is-grouped-multiline.input
__proto__: HTMLCollection
```

then I tried to access it:

```
console.log(inp[0]);
```

but it returned:

```
undefined
```

I tried to run it in chrome devTools console and it worked just fine

Here is example code:

```
<script>
    var inp = document.getElementsByClassName("tagsinput field is-grouped is-grouped-multiline input");
    console.log(inp);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma-tagsinput@2.0.0/dist/js/bulma-tagsinput.min.js">
    </script>
<script>
    bulmaTagsinput.attach();
</script>
```

Comment: Could you upload the HTML Element that you're trying to select?

Comment: Parse has a very specific definition for computing that doesn't apply here. You aren't parsing anything.

Comment: Probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17546953) issue, but without more info, we can't say for sure (nor give a solution to the problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your added code example, it looks like the problem is a race condition.  You're attempting to access the element before it's added to the DOM.

Adding a `window.load` event listener should fix the problem:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma-tagsinput@2.0.0/dist/js/bulma-tagsinput.min.js"></script>
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
        bulmaTagsinput.attach();
        var inp = document.getElementsByClassName("tagsinput field is-grouped is-grouped-multiline input");
        console.log(inp);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That applies if you use that code directly in the console, but OP mentioned that it works fine from the DevTools console.

Comment: @Ivar the code example hadn't been posted before, which is why I assumed OP was confusing the output with the printed value.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(inp[0]);
}, 1000);
```

Problem was that I was trying to parse an object that didn't exist.