# Accessing individual properties from object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a object saved in state here is what is looks like when console.logged.

```
[{…}]
0:
NameOfUser: "James"
QuestionStatus: "Complete                      "
Date: (2) ["2020-03-10T14:13:45.257Z", "2020-03-10T14:13:45.257Z"]
AssignedWorkstation: "hello"
Email: "James@gmail.com"
ContactNumber: "12345678987654321"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

to console log this I have just done this

```
console.log(this.state.WSAHeader);
```

How would I access the individual properties of this object.

I have tried

```
console.log(this.state.WSAHeader.NameOfUser);
```

This says it is undefined.
How would I just access for example the NameOfUser property from this object stored in state.

I have also tried

```
console.log(this.state.WSAHeader[0].NameOfUser);
```

I am just looking for a suggestion for what is going wrong.

whole class

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      answeredQuestions: [],
      WSAHeader: []
    };
    this.getWSAAnsweredQuestions = this.getWSAAnsweredQuestions.bind(this);
    this.getWSAHeader = this.getWSAHeader.bind(this);
  }

  getWSAAnsweredQuestions() {
    let data = {
      WSAId: this.props.location.state.WSAId
    };
    fetch("/get-completed-questions", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
      .then(recordset => recordset.json())
      .then(results => {
        this.setState({ answeredQuestions: results.recordset });
        console.log(this.state.answeredQuestions);
      });
  }

  getWSAHeader() {
    let data = {
      WSAId: this.props.location.state.WSAId
    };
    fetch("/get-WSA-header", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
      .then(recordset => recordset.json())
      .then(results => {
        this.setState({ WSAHeader: results.recordset });
        console.log(this.state.WSAHeader);
      });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getWSAHeader();
    this.getWSAAnsweredQuestions();
  }
  render() {
    // alert(this.state.WSAHeader.NameOfUser);
    console.log(this.state.WSAHeader);
    console.log(this.state.WSAHeader[0].NameOfUser);
    console.log(this.state.WSAHeader.QuestionStatus);

    return (
      <>
        <Header />
        {/* <h3 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Workstation Assessment</h3> */}

        <DisplayWSAHeader WSAHeader={this.state.WSAHeader} />
        <WSAAnsweredQuestions
          WSAHeader={this.state.WSAHeader.AssignedWorkstation}
          answeredQuestions={this.state.answeredQuestions}
          amountOfQuestions={this.state.answeredQuestions.length}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What did this one `console.log(this.state.WSAHeader[0].NameOfUser);` do? The example is formatted a little strange in the question, but that seems to be the correct way.

Comment: Cannot read property 'NameOfUser' of undefined

Comment: Thats the error it logged

Comment: Could you add the full object to the question?

Comment: This code looks fine; there might be problem in `this` binding

Comment: Have edited the question for the whole class

Comment: It's possibly not defined at the time of `console.log`. Before you expand the array in the object, what does it look like? Does it say `length: 0` then only when you expand it does it say `length: 1`?

Comment: @ShaunE.Tobias is correct, you are loading that data after the component mounts, so it will be an empty array for at least the first render. You'll need to check its existence before accessing a property.

Comment: Once you can verify that the array is populated, `console.log(this.state.WSAHeader[0].NameOfUser)` is the correct syntax.

Comment: @BrianThompson you are correct. I made a button to test. ```  <button
          onClick={e => alert(this.state.WSAHeader[0].NameOfUser)}
        ></button>```

Comment: that displayed the information I wanted so thanks guys ! If someone would like to post a answer stating this I am happy to accept :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Comment: Also see: [Can't access object property, even though it shows up in a console log](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17546953/1218980)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Answer from the question's comments*

It's not defined at the time of `console.log`. This is true if before you expand the array in the console, it says `length: 0` but then when you expand it, it says `length: 1`.

This is because you're loading the data after the component mounts so it will be empty the first time around. If you check that the array has been populated first before accessing it, it will work.