# Acessing sub array inside an "empty" array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have this output when I do a console log:

[image: I have this output when I do a console log]

What I want to do is access all five elements but I can't do it. If I do `this.tempLines[0]` it says that is undefined. Same with `this.tempLines[0][0]` for example. And same with `this.tempLines.lines`
The only thing that prints is when I do `this.tempLines`.

This is the way I push elements to `tempLines`. I did that to store data inside a subscribe:

```
retrieveLines(){
   this.lineService.getAll().subscribe(result=>{
       this.lines=result;
       for(let data of this.lines) {
          this.tempLines.push(data)
       }
   });
}
```

And finally I declare my two array vars like this

```
lines:any=new Array<any>();
public tempLines:any=new Array<any>();
```

PS: I know there is many redundancy but I do that because I want to store outside the subscribe method the list of lines to use it in other methods and if I just say that `this.lines= result` when I console log outside subscribe method I have nothing.

Comment: Can you provide the sample response data response?

Comment: Your "redundancy" isn't helping the way you think it does. No matter what, you're going to have to wait until the subscribe function runs before accessing data in `this.lines` or  `this.tempLines`. That's asynchronous programming.

Comment: See also [Can't access object property, even though it shows up in a console log](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17546953/215552)

Comment: Heretic Monkey, i understand what u sayin. the thing is that i have many tables. and for example in this case i need to get all Lines and inside all lines do a findByKey() inside another mongo table and after that do another findByKey() in another table. i need three subscribes. and only can do that if all information of last subscribe is stored. if i do the third subscribe inside the main subscribe i loose all data