# array object working if we hardcode data but not working when we populate data from Node js to react js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

I have array object in react Js, when I hardcode the data in React js and execute it is working, same data sending from Node JS and in React JS it is not displaying.

Please see the codesandbox link, my code working https://codesandbox.io/s/reactbootstrapcarousel-forked-4selu?file=/src/index.js.

```
import React,{useState} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Carousel } from "react-bootstrap";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [eventList, setEventList] = useState([{
                                    eventName: 'Sankranti',
                                    eventDate: '2021-01-21T00:00:00.000Z',
                                    merchantid: 'tp012345'
                                  },
                                  {
                                    eventName: 'Sankranti 1',
                                    eventDate: '2021-01-26T00:00:00.000Z',
                                    merchantid: 'tp012345'
                                  }])
  const eventListRender = eventList.length > 0 ?
                          eventList.map((item,index) => { 
                          return <Carousel.Item>{item.eventName}</Carousel.Item>
                          }) :
                          <Carousel.Item>No upcoming events</Carousel.Item>
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <Carousel>
          {eventListRender}
      </Carousel>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Same code not working when I am passing data from Node JS to React JS via axios, but data is coming from Node JS to React JS. It shows as undefined ( item event name:  undefined.)

Please find my code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel'
import axios from 'axios';
import DashboardNavBar from './DashboardNavBar';
import Header from './Header';

const DashboardPage = (props) => {
    const [eventList, setEventList] = useState([])
    const [index, setIndex] = useState()

    if (!props.profileData) {
        useEffect(() => {
            (async () => {
                const eventsList = await axios.get(
                    "http://localhost:3000/api/dashboard"
                );
                    console.log(eventsList.data)
                    const response = eventsList.data
                    setEventList(eventList => [...eventList, response])
                    if(!response){
                        setErrorMsg('Please create Event and then add User !!')
                    }
            })();
        }, []);
    }

    const eventListRender = eventList.length > 0 ?
                          eventList.map((item,index) => { 
                              console.log('item event name: ', item.eventName)
                          return <Carousel.Item>{item.eventName}</Carousel.Item>
                          }) :
                          <Carousel.Item>No upcoming events</Carousel.Item>

    return (
        <div>
            <DashboardNavBar />
            <Header />
            <p >Welcome !!!!!!</p>
            <Carousel>
                {eventListRender}
            </Carousel>
        </div>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    profileData: state.auth.profileData
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps) (DashboardPage);
```

Please find console result for above code.
[image]

Comment: When you hard code the data, the retrieval is synchronous. When you use an async function, it is asynchronous, so there is a point at which `item` is empty.

Comment: Item has data. Please find updated console result.

Comment: when we try to read item.eventName it returns undefined.

Comment: read [Can't access object property, even though it shows up in a console log](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17546953/215552)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to spread your API result as well, because it is an array:

```js
setEventList(eventList => [...eventList, ...response])
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use hooks on conditionally.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

```
XXXX if (!props.profileData) { XXXX
        useEffect(() => {
            (async () => {
                const eventsList = await axios.get(
                    "http://localhost:3000/api/dashboard"
                );
                    console.log(eventsList.data)
                    const response = eventsList.data
                    setEventList(eventList => [...eventList, ...response])
                    if(!response){
                        setErrorMsg('Please create Event and then add User !!')
                    }
            })();
        }, []);
    }
```

instead use below

```
            useEffect(() => {
             if(!props.profileData) {
                (async () => {
                    const eventsList = await axios.get(
                        "http://localhost:3000/api/dashboard"
                    );
                        console.log(eventsList.data)
                        const response = eventsList.data
                        setEventList(eventList => [...eventList, ...response])
                        if(!response){
                            setErrorMsg('Please create Event and then add User !!')
                        }
                })();
            }
            }, [props.profileData]);
        }
```

Looks like issue is at .map logic.

```
 const eventListRender = eventList.length > 0 ?
                          eventList.map((item) => { 
                              console.log('item: ', item)
                              console.log('item event name: ', item.eventName)
                          return <Carousel.Item>{item.eventName}</Carousel.Item>
                          }) :
                          <Carousel.Item>No upcoming events</Carousel.Item>
```

[image]

Comment: not working still same results

Comment: Are you sure `props.profileData` null or undefined?

Comment: yes it is null.

Comment: your `item` has an array, so if you try   `console.log('item event name: ', item[0].eventName)` it should log. 

So you need to spread API response too 
`setEventList(eventList => [...eventList, ..response])`

Comment: after adding item[0].eventName it got this error . Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'eventName' of undefined

Comment: it worked when I add only setEventList(eventList => [...eventList, ..response]). I kept item[0].eventName to item.eventName, it worked. Thanks lot.

Comment: first time it will be empty. I have updated the code you can use above one now.

Comment: Don't wrap hooks with the condition.