# Vue.js + Typescript : Class-based fetching with Axios using DTO architecture

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I tried to apply architecture found [here](https://medium.com/js-dojo/vue-js-typescript-best-practices-5-class-based-fetching-with-axios-using-dto-architecture-a2bf80102162):

I don't succeed retrieving array of objects Release to be then be displayed inside component via v-list. I would like to extract the list of object from the returned promise. Not sure how to do this in Release.vue.

**ReleaseApi.ts**

```
import Axios from "axios";
import Release, {ReleaseDTO} from '@/models/Release';

interface RequestInterface {  
  map(arg0: (data: ReleaseDTO) => Release): Release[] | Promise<Release[]>;
  data: ReleaseDTO[]
}

export abstract class ReleasesApi {

private static instanceAxios = Axios.create({}); //baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/'

  static async getAllReleases(): Promise<Release[]>{
    const response = await this.instanceAxios.get<RequestInterface>('api/releases');
    return response.data.map(data => new Release(data));
  }

}
```

**Release.vue**

```
<template>
    <h1>Releases</h1>
    <div v-if="loading">
      <h1>Asynchroneous called when mount state</h1>
        <v-list>
          <v-list-item :key="index" v-for="(release, index) in releases">
          {{release.name}} <br/>

          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
    </div>
</template>
 
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref,reactive,onMounted} from 'vue';
import { ReleasesApi  } from '../api/ReleasesApi'; 
import Release from '@/models/Release';
//https://github.com/kstraszewski/playground-vue/blob/class-based-fetching/src/views/Home.vue

export default defineComponent ({
setup (){

   let loading  = ref(false);
   let releases :any = ref([]);

  onMounted (  async () =>  {
       loading.value  = false;
       releases.value =  await ReleasesApi.getAllReleases();
       console.log(JSON.stringify(releases.value));
       loading.value  = true;

  })

   // expose to template
  return {loading,releases};

}
});

  </script>
```

**Release.ts**

```
export class ReleaseInterface{
  release_id?: number;
  date?: Date;
  name?: string;

}

export class ReleaseDTO implements ReleaseInterface{
  release_id?: number = 0;
  date?: Date = new Date(2012, 0, 1);
  name?: string = "";

}

export default class Release extends ReleaseDTO {

  constructor(dto: ReleaseDTO){
    super();
    Object.assign(this, dto);
  }

  get fullName(): string {
    return `${this.release_id}  ${this.name}`;
  }

}
```

**Using :**

**let releases : Release[] | Promise<Release[] = ref([]);**

> ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error
> 4:52:53 PM
>
> error  in
> /home/jp/eclipse-workspace/Vue/scs/frontend/src/components/Release.vue.ts
>
> [tsl] ERROR in
> /home/jp/eclipse-workspace/Vue/scs/frontend/src/components/Release.vue.ts(10,49)
> TS1005: '>' expected.
>
> @ ./src/components/Release.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts 1:0-327
> 1:0-327 1:328-644 1:328-644  @ ./src/components/Release.vue  @
> ./src/main.ts  @ multi
> (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.226.145:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node
> (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.ts
>
> Issues checking in progress... ERROR in
> src/components/Release.vue:24:8 TS2322: Type 'Ref<never[]>' is not
> assignable to type 'Release[] | Promise<Release[]>'.   Type
> 'Ref<never[]>' is missing the following properties from type
> 'Promise<Release[]>': then, catch, [Symbol.toStringTag], finally
> 22 |
> 23 |    let loading  = ref(false);
>
> > 24 |    let releases : Release[] | Promise<Release[] = ref([]);
> > |        ^^^^^^^^
> > 25 |
> > 26 |   onMounted (  async () =>  {
> > 27 |        loading.value  = false;
>
> ERROR in src/components/Release.vue:28:17 TS2339: Property 'value'
> does not exist on type 'Release[] | Promise<Release[]>'.   Property
> 'value' does not exist on type 'Release[]'.
> 26 |   onMounted (  async () =>  {
> 27 |        loading.value  = false;
>
> > 28 |        releases.value =  await ReleasesApi.getAllReleases();
> > |                 ^^^^^
> > 29 |        console.log(JSON.stringify(releases.value));
> > 30 |        loading.value  = true;
> > 31 |
>
> ERROR in src/components/Release.vue:29:44 TS2339: Property 'value'
> does not exist on type 'Release[] | Promise<Release[]>'.   Property
> 'value' does not exist on type 'Release[]'.
> 27 |        loading.value  = false;
> 28 |        releases.value =  await ReleasesApi.getAllReleases();
>
> > 29 |        console.log(JSON.stringify(releases.value));
> > |                                            ^^^^^
> > 30 |        loading.value  = true;
> > 31 |
> > 32 |   })

Comment: You're missing basics, it would be the same without DTO and any extra things. You're trying to access promise result synchronously, which isn't possible by the definition of promises. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call . Asynchronous code belongs to onMounted. You can write it conveniently with async/await but I'd suggest to not do this before figuring out how it works with raw promises and `then`.

Comment: Yeah I'm beginner and I'd like to use this example to better understand the whole stuff. I changed using async onMounted function. The loading is passing to true so text is displayed but not v-list items. I don't understand why releases don't"t wait the return of the call to ReleaseApi to be then displayed in the view. Also I dont know how to initialise correcly the releases value and If I need the use of Promise.resolve somewhere. In the console releases display well the array with two object Release. Any help would be appreciate. :)

Comment: It doesn't wait because you didn't make it wait. You physically can't wait for *asynchronous* operation in *synchronous* code. Consider checking the link above, it discusses fundamental things that are relevant to your case. You're misusing a ref, its purpose is to hold a reference to a value, hence the word. You already passed original `releases` to a view with `return`, it will be clueless of any other value you assign to it, it should be never reassigned, instead should be `releases.value = ...`.

Comment: `Promise.resolve` converts non-promise to a promise. If you already have existing promise like here, you dont need it or `new Promise`. As for console, that's another common thing, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546953/cant-access-object-property-even-though-it-shows-up-in-a-console-log

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I changed again. It works. Still I don't know how should I declare releases in the setup(). So I use :any but that's not the best way to do it. And using  let releases : Release[] | Promise<Release[]> = ref([]); give plenty of erros. (see update)

Comment: `releases` is never a promise. It's not a value but a ref (an object with `value` key). It should be `const releases = ref<Release[]>([])`, const because it's never reassigned.

Comment: Yep true ! Thanks a lot !