# value not change in key value pair (javascript)

Tags: javascript, dictionary

Hello I am wondering why the value is not changing in my key, value pair set. I believe its not changing because it looks the same before and after using `console.log()`. I have a picture of the console. It might be an easy solution that has to do something async happening but I can not think of the solution! The code looks like:

```js
console.log(files[index])

files[index].name = "lol"

console.log(files[index])
```

[image: 1]

Comment: For who someone come here later,
below link will be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546953/cant-access-object-property-even-though-it-shows-up-in-a-console-log?page=2&tab=scoredesc#tab-top

Comment: Sorry, wrong pages query.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546953/cant-access-object-property-even-though-it-shows-up-in-a-console-log?page=1&tab=scoredesc#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

I have replicated your issue in the console, and can see it does work.

[image]

You need to make sure your `'index'` is in quotes.