# Where is data located in an object?

Tags: javascript, html

For taking data from a form, I use `new FormData`. Please see the sample code below.
Click submit and the data will be displayed in the console.

There is an array of data in the first log (using spread operator), and there is an object of data in the second log, but when I look up the data in the object in console log I can't find it. I want to know where the data in Object is located.

```js
const  form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(form)
    
    // first log is an array
    console.log([...data])

    // second log is an Object
    console.log(data)
})
```

```html
<body>
<form>
    <label >input1</label>
    <input name="input1"  type="text"  value='test1' />

    <label >input1</label>
    <input  name="input1"  type="text"  value='test2' />

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>

</body>
```

Comment: I think the question is related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546953/cant-access-object-property-even-though-it-shows-up-in-a-console-log  Thanks!