# Vue js getters returns always empty

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a vue 3 app with vuex, below is my store :

```
import VueX from 'vuex'
import ProductService from '@/services/ProductService'
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state:{ products : [] },
    getters : {
        getProductFromSlug(state){
            console.log(state) // <= state with products retrieved (please see first screen capture below)
            console.log(state.products) // <== empty ??? (please see second screen capture)
            return state.products.filter( product => {
                return product.slug == 'my-slug'
            })
        }
    },
    actions:{
        fetchProducts(context){
            ProductService.getProducts().then( response => context.commit('setProducts', response.data) )
        }
    },
    mutations: { setProducts(state, products) { this.state.products = products } }
})
```

From my component, i want to retrieve a product by slug :

```
... 
created() {
    store.dispatch('fetchProducts')
    console.log(store.getters.productFromSlug)
}
```

First output of state ==> [image]

Output of state.products ==> [image]

Anyone can explain me please why i get empty values from the getProductFromSlug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Console output shouldn't be used as a reliable way of debugging. Here [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546953/cant-access-object-property-even-though-it-shows-up-in-a-console-log) is observed, an array is passed by reference to console, it doesn't reflect the current state of things.

The mistake here is that promises aren't chained correctly, this results in race condition. `dispatch` always returns a promise, asynchronous actions should always return a promise. Then it's not waited. It should be:

```
async created() {
    await store.dispatch('fetchProducts')
    console.log(store.getters.productFromSlug)
}
```

and

```
fetchProducts(context){
  return ProductService.getProducts().then(...)
}
```

Comment: Thank you but adding async and await from created output same results

Comment: There should be both fixes, see the explanation

Comment: yes, i fixed both : return the ProductService from 'fetchProduct' and async/await the store.dispatch(...), i missed something ?

Comment: Then it should work as intended, these are the only problems. Make sure you don't run old code somehow. If the problem persists, please, provide a way to reproduce the problem.

Comment: ah, when console.log(product) inside the filter method, i get each product, i suspect the comparaison return product.slug == 'my-slug'

Comment: You have `console.log(state.products) // <== empty` in original code, it should give a clear idea if the problem persists

Comment: So, it's my mistake, i didn't return the product.slug == 'my-slug', thank you, it works now