# Why object property is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I'm trying to use reduxtoolkit and want to create addtocart function and when try to set the payload I can't access the object property of my data.

```
const {data:foods,isPending,error} = useFetch('http://localhost:8000/foods')
const [data, setData] = useState(foods)
useEffect(()=>{
    setData(foods)
},[foods])    console.log(data)
console.log(data.name)
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const addToCart = () => {
    dispatch(
        cartActions.addToCart({
            name :data.name,
            id:data.id,
            price:data.price,
        })
    )
}
```

**The Error**: when I'm trying to log the object property it's returning undefined but when I log the data it showing up

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGzrO.png]

Comment: Your data didn't load yet, that's why

Comment: You are also getting `undefined` from `console.log` in line 47, but you ignored it

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Use `console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))` to log the value of `data` at the time `console.log` is called instead of the lazy loading browsers use.

Comment: `data` is an array - it doesn't have a `name` property.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't access object property, even though it shows up in a console log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546953/cant-access-object-property-even-though-it-shows-up-in-a-console-log)

Answer (score 2):

the reason I think you reciebe an array, you need add a index for get access:

```
 dispatch(
        cartActions.addToCart({
            name :data[1].name,
            id: data[1].id,
            price: data.[1]price,
        })
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can clearly see that what you recieve from your API call is an `array`, which has no `name` property. However, items in this array have `name` property (`data[0].name`). What you need to do is to pass `index` of an item you want to add to your cart into `addToCart` function and based on that, access the right `data[index]` item variable

```
const addToCart = (itemIndex) => {
    dispatch(
        cartActions.addToCart({
            name :data[itemIndex].name,
            id:data[itemIndex].id,
            price:data[itemIndex].price,
        })
    )
}
```