# VueUse useStorage not updating stored object values

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, local-storage, vueuse

I'm trying to update an object property inside my localStorage but `useStorage` doesn't update the object if it exists in the store.

in **`App.vue`**:

```
routeStore.query = {
  tab: 'products',
  subTab: 1,
  search: '',
  article: '',
}
console.log(routeStore.query)
console.log(localStorage.query)
useStorage('query', routeStore.query)
console.log(localStorage.query)
```

**`console`**:

```
Proxy(Object) {tab: 'products', subTab: 1, search: '', article: ''}
{"tab":"products","subTab":2,"search":"","article":""}
{"tab":"products","subTab":2,"search":"","article":""}
```

Desired outcome is for `query.subTab` to be `1`. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Console is unnecessary contains up-to-date info. Don't use it to debug objects. It's unknown if it's incorrect observation that's the problem here, or something else. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546953/cant-access-object-property-even-though-it-shows-up-in-a-console-log

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so by default useStorage doesn't sync the default object with localStorage. See here https://vueuse.org/core/useStorage/#merge-defaults

Try using `mergeDefaults`.

```
routeStore.query = {
  tab: 'products',
  subTab: 1,
  search: '',
  article: '',
}

useStorage(
  'query',
  routeStore.query,
  localStorage,
  { mergeDefaults: true } // <--
)
```

Comment: This works but strangely it does so only once. When I want to change the `subTab` propery consecutively, it just stays at the value of the initial change. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov useStorage isn't a glorified localStorage.setItem You don't sync routeStore and a store that useStorage returns, you actually ignore the latter. There should be a single source of truth, and it has to be be a store that useStorage returns, there may be no need for routeStore depending on your case

Comment: This part about sync is misleading because default object isn't synced at all. It's copied.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Merge Defaults](https://vueuse.org/core/useStorage/#merge-defaults) option

```
useStorage('query', routeStore.query,  localStorage, { mergeDefaults: true })
```

Here is JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/12ctwmzg/