# unable to access object data from angular services

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, object, console.log

i am building a chat website , i have a component called "chat Box" , i need data of both the users to be fetched from firebase , i have stored the key of other user in the service, (can confirm as i can see the details in console),i am unable to get the key of the other users stored in service

i tried
   `console.log(this.details.user.OtherUser);` 
but it gives undefined

but from the     `console.log(this.details.user);` i am getting the following correct object .

in short ,the following code

```
    console.log(`/${this.details.user.OtherUser}`)
console.log(this.details.user);
console.log(this.details.user.OtherUser);
console.log("above from constructor")
```

[console.log statements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnjXo.png)

gives me
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F13zP.png)

what i am doing wrong?

Comment: I can’t see field OtherUser inside this.details.user. I guess this is a reason of undefined.

Comment: details in this component is the DetailsService the I have console logged , I am sorry for the confusion , I have added a picture for you understanding @EvgenyGurevich

Comment: Look at my first comment, it was edited

Comment: yes, i am unable to see OtherUser when I console log this.details.user, but when I click the small arrow I am getting the OtherUser field as well, visible in "output" link @EvgenyGurevich

Comment: Then show your component code

Comment: My guess is that console.log(JSON.stringify(this.details.user)) will also give undefined for the reason explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546953/cant-access-object-property-even-though-it-shows-up-in-a-console-log)

Comment: sure, [link](https://codeshare.io/vwBbN4) here, @EvgenyGurevich

Comment: thank you guys for the help!! @James I found the code causing the bug , its fixed